# Deriving the Bring-Jerrard quintic using a cubic Tschirnhausen transformation

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

One can simultaneously eliminate three terms from the general quintic using a *quartic* Tschirnhausen transformation. The 4th parameter of the quartic allows it to be done in radicals and details are in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542108/how-to-transform-a-general-higher-degree-five-or-higher-equation-to-normal-form/). But I found out (back in 2006) that a rational *cubic* Tschirnhausen transformation can do the same.

As usual, we start with the principal quintic,

$$y^5+\color{blue}{5}ry^2+\color{blue}{5}sy+t = 0\tag{1}$$

(with the "5" added for simplicity later) but with the *cubic* transformation,

$$y^3+ay^2+by+c =z(y+d)\tag{2}$$

where the *extra* parameter allows the same Bring-Jerrard "trick". Let $c=3r$, and eliminating $y$ between (1) and (2), we get the new quintic,

$c_0z^5+c_1z^4+c_2z^3+c_3z^2+c_4z+c_5=0\tag{3}$

where,

$$c_1 = -6 d r^2 + 4 d^3 s + 3 r s - d^2 t - (3 d^2 r - 4 d s + t)(b - a d)\tag{4}$$

and so on for the other $c_i$. Solve for $a$, substitute into $c_1=c_2=0$ and, after factoring, one gets the quadratic that is *only* in the unknown $d$,

$(18 r^2 s^2 - 9 r^3 t - 2 s t^2) + (-27 r^3 s + 16 s^2 t - 3 r t^2) d + (27 r^4 - 32 s^3 + 12 r s t)d^2 = 0\tag{5}$

Solving for $d$, one can then set $c_3=0$ which is only a *cubic* in the last unknown $b$,

$$e_0 b^3+e_1b^2+e_2b+e_3=0\tag{6}$$

thus solving $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ in radicals.

*Notes*:

1. The discriminant of the quadratic in (5) in fact has the same discriminant (up to a numerical factor) as the principal quintic.
2. If the process is applied to higher degrees, then the equation in $d$ in (5) also rises in degree. For the principal sextic, it is already a quartic. Thus, the transformation is in radicals only for deg $\leq 6$.

***Question***:

How do we explain *why* the transformation exists from *basic principles* (in the same manner Sen did in the post mentioned above)?

Comment: Well, it's still classified as a [Tschirnhausen transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TschirnhausenTransformation.html), $$y=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$ of the equation $f(x)=0$. The [Brioschi quintic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrioschiQuinticForm.html) also employs a rational Tschirnhausen, $$y=\frac{ax+b}{c^{-1}x^2-3}$$

Comment: I have derived the process of transformation of principal quintic into a Bring-Jerrard quintic by your transformation from power-sum formulas. Would that be qualified as an answer to this question?

Comment: It would be interesting to look at.

Comment: Since only the roots are affected by the transformations, any two classes of transformations with equal number of parameters are equivalent to each other (excluding some degenerate values of the parameters). Your rational transformation has 4 parameters, so it should be equivalent to a quartic Tschirnhausen transformation. This point of view might hopefully be of use.