# Substitution to linear + nth power form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring

Given an arbitrary polynomial:

$$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 ... a_nx^n$$

Does there exist a series of substitutions (or single substitution if you choose to combine them) that leaves this function in the form:

$$p_1w + p_2w^r$$

I am aware there are substitutions (referred to as polynomial depression) that leave the polynomial in the form:

$$p_1 + p_2w + rw^n$$

For example in this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form

Comment: No and no. The first binomial form is solvable, and any _radical_ transformation would contradict insolvability of general polynomials. The second is a trinomial form and it is provably true that a sextic cannot be reduced to that which is essentially of the form $z^n + z + t$. See _Hilbert's $13$th problem_ for an essentially similar conjecture for septics.

Comment: Actually, it's yes. He _didn't_ specify that it be in radicals, only if there was such a well-defined transformation. And the Tschirnhausen can do it (but one must be careful to point out that the transformation is generally _not_ in radicals).

Comment: Yes, it's yes if nonradical transformations are allowed, as I recall you did from one of your blogpost transforming a Brioshic to a DeMoivre via modular $j$ (This is replaced by my previous arguments. Surely $N = F(X, Y)$ is possible, which slipped from my mind for a bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given the general equation,

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0 =0\tag{1}$$

you can use a deg $n-1$ *Tschirnhausen transformation*,

$$y =b_nx^{n-1}+b_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\dots b_1$$

to reduce (1) to binomial form,

$$y^n+c_0 = 0$$

Unfortunately, in general the unknowns $b_i$  entail solving an equation of at least $(n-1)!$ degree, hence *is not in radicals* for $n\geq5$. (For $n=4$, the system results in a solvable sextic.)

But you can eliminate, in radicals, the three terms $x^{n-1},x^{n-2},x^{n-3}$ simultaneously. A clear step-by-step description is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542108/how-to-transform-a-general-higher-degree-five-or-higher-equation-to-normal-form).

Comment: This is quite informative but doesn't answer exactly what I was asking. Can we transform the equation into a linear term + some-power term as opposed to constant term and normal power term as you did?

Comment: But the form $P(w)=p_1w+p_2w^r = w(p_1+p_2w^{r-1})$ is factorable. You do know that the transformation you cited (Bring quintics) is applied on _equations_, hence the polynomial is necessarily equated to $P(w) = 0$, and one can factor out that $w$.

Comment: Does that mean knowing such a transformation implies you can solve the the equation if the original polynomial set to 0?

Comment: Ah, you are using "*polynomials*" and "*equations*" interchangeably. The transformations that you cited are applied to ***equations*** (in particular, the quintic for the *Bring radical*) . Kindly edit your post and ***put zeros*** at the end of your three equations, and you will see that the second one is addressed by my answer.

Comment: I see why as it is