# Solutions to quintic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, galois-theory, quintics

Abel's Theorem shows that there is no general formula that gives the solution to $x^5+Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E=0$ with radicals. My math is not sufficient to understand Abel's theorem. Considering motivation from lower degrees where we try to remove terms, e.g. depressing a cubic, does it(or other theorems) say anything about the existence of special case formulas in radicals? For example, $D=0$ or $B=C$. I am less interested in the case $E=0$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814264/reduce-quintic-equation?rq=1). Even if several coefficients are zero, like $x^5-2x+1$, it cannot be solved by radicals in general.

Comment: There is plenty of information in the Wikipedia article about [quintic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function). I have collated this information in the [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5802).

Comment: $E=0$ amounts to a quartic. $D=0$ is equivalent to $A=0$.

Answer (score 2):

By shifting the unknown by $-\dfrac A4$, you deplete the equation and absorb one degree of freedom. So introducing a constraint such as $D=0$ or $B=C$ does not make the equation less general.

$D=0$ is what you get by changing $x\leftrightarrow \dfrac1x$ and depleting.

By resolution of a cubic, you can find a shift the enforces $B=C$.