# Reducing the Quintic in the Spirit of Cardano

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have been trying to follow a proof of the Abel Ruffini theorem as described in "Mathematical Omnibus", which starts with a quintic in the Bring Gerrard form. However, the only things that I could find on the reduction of the General quintic to the Bring Gerrard form without using [resultants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542108/how-to-transform-a-general-higher-degree-five-or-higher-equation-to-normal-form), something that I want to avoid as they look very complicated. I was wondering if there was a substitution that could be made along the lines of how Cardano [solved the depressed cubic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) that could transform the quintic into the Bring Gerrard form. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!