# What's the size of an angle in a triangle with sides $\sin(x), \cos(x),$ and $\tan(x)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> Imagining a scalene triangle with sides $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ and $\tan(x)$, how would you find angle $x$ if it was between $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ when $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I tried using the law of cosines but it lead nowhere and honestly haven't gone very far.
$$\cos(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-\tan^2(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
\cos(x)=\frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{\sin(2x)}$$

Comment: Please show the work you did using the Law of Cosines. (That certainly seems the appropriate way to approach the problem.) Someone may be able to easily identify a simple algebraic or conceptual error, or suggest a next step, without having to duplicate your effort. ... Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3477429/edit) to add details.

Comment: We must have $x\le 54.717469^{\circ}$

Comment: Your work is a good start! Rather than combining $2\sin x\cos x$ into $\sin 2x$ (a valid operation), I cleared the fractions and wrote everything in terms of $\sin x$. The result isn't pretty, however.

Comment: I guess simplifying $tan^2(x)$ into $\frac{sin^2(x)}{cos^2(x)}$ could help, but I think it becomes too messy and doesn't add anything to the process so I omitted it.

Comment: At some point, you want to solving for something, so you'll need to write the equation in terms of a single something. Upon clearing fractions (and re-writing $\tan^2x$), you find yourself with even powers of cosines and odd powers of sine; this suggests writing everything in terms of $\sin x$. I agree that it's messy, though. I got a quintic equation that had to be solved numerically ... but perhaps I made an error somewhere.

Comment: @Blue The same here

Comment: Numerically it's $x \approx 0.362803$ which is about $20.7871^\circ$.

Comment: Where you write "how would you find angle $x$ if it was between $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$", are you saying that either $\cos(x) < x < \sin(x)$ or $\sin(x) < x < \cos(x)$ must be true?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated No, I'm referring to the physical position of the angle as it's between the sides $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the law of cosines, we have that $$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(C)$$
In this case, we have that $c = \tan(x), a = \cos(x), b = \sin(x)$, and $C = x$.

Plugging those in, we get $$\tan^2(x) = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) - 2\cos(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

After making the simplification $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$ and multiplying by $\cos^2(x)$, the result is $$\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)-2\cos^4(x)\sin(x)$$

Making the substitution $u = \sin(x)$, we get $$2u^{5}-4u^{3}+2u^{2}+2u-1=0$$

This is a quintic equation with no closed form for the roots. However, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2u%5E5+-+4u%5E3+%2B+2u%5E2+%2B+2u-1+%3D+0) says the relevant root is approximately $0.463$. $x$ is then the $\arcsin$ of this, which means that $$x \approx 0.481$$

Comment: WA also gives a solution $u \approx -0.785$, which corresponds to a triangle having sides $\sin x', \cos x', \tan x'$ where $x'$ is the _exterior_ angle formed by the first two of those sides.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for the roots - and by extension, $x$ - *in radicals*, but there is a solution in special functions.

Comment: @Jam What would the solution be with special functions?

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on the answers by [**Automatically Generated**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/595055/automaticallygenerated) and [**Claude Leibovici**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici), despite quintics not being generally solvable in radicals, we can obtain a closed form solution by permitting special functions, albeit an unreadably long solution that goes beyond the scope of the original question. Following the excellent answer on [Question 542108](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542228) by [**Tito Piezas III**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4781/tito-piezas-iii), we can reduce the quintic $p_1(x)=2x^5−4x^3+2x^2+2x−1$, first to principal quintic form, then to [Bring quintic form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BringQuinticForm.html). We achieve this by applying a quadratic [Tschirnhausen transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TschirnhausenTransformation.html) to $p_1$, attaining $p_2(y)=y^{5}-0.455y^{2}-0.531y-0.116$, where $y=x^{2}+0.148x-0.8$ *. We then follow this with a quartic Tschirnhausen transformation on $p_2$, for $p_3(z)=z^{5}-0.108z+0.0131$, where $z=y^{4}-0.477y^{3}+0.317y^{2}-1.219y-0.295$. This is finally converted to Bring quintic form with the substitution $z=0.108^{{1}/{4}}t$, giving us $p_4(t)=t^5-t+0.211$. We can then return to the desired root through the correctly chosen chain of roots, $t=0.939\to z=0.539\to y=-0.510\to x=0.463$.

Then, we may solve $p_4$ using the technique from Piezas III's answer in [Question 540964](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions/541027). Using the notation from that answer, we would have $k = (0.268-0.625 i)$ and $\frac{(k^2)^{1/8}}{2\cdot 5^{3/4}\sqrt{k(1-k^2)}}=(0.139 + 0.0234 i)$. The root we desire corresponds to $n=4$, so $p=(-0.784 + 1.177 i)+16\cdot 4$, so then for $j=0,1,2,3,4,5$, we have $\small S_j=(-0.418-1.074i),\ (3.533-0.341i),\ (0.495+0.848i), (-0.000+1.000i),\ (-0.706+0.704i),\ (0.005-0.140i)$. Using this technique, the root $t=0.939$ is expressible in a closed form, using radicals, [the complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), $K(x)$, and the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function), $\eta(x)$. Therefore, so too is the root $x=0.463$ of $p_1$, as is the size of the angle in question.

---

* Each coefficient from this point onwards *has* a closed form in radicals but as they are unreasonably large, I've given rounded decimals only. See **Tito Piezas III's** answer for a full account of the substitutions, transformations and derivations of the coefficients. I'd advise using a computer algebra solver, like Maple or Mathematica when using this technique due to the volume of operations and terms. NB: Some values I've listed may have rounding errors.

Comment: This is more than impressive ! $\to +1$

Answer (score 3):

Starting from @automaticallyGenerated's answer, facing a quintic polynomial, tou will need a numerical method.

Let us consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\sin^2(x)- \cos^2(x)+2\cos^4(x)\sin(x)$$ and use Newton method starting with $x_0=0$; this will provide the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.000000 \\
 1 & 0.500000 \\
 2 & 0.480810 \\
 3 & 0.481195
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Graphing or using inspection, we can notice that the solution is close to $\frac \pi 6$. So, making a Taylor expansion around this point, we have
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{16}+t-\frac{392 }{507}t^2+\frac{7552 }{19773}t^3+\frac{504320
   }{771147}t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $t=\frac{13\sqrt{3}}{16}  \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)$.

Now, using series reversion (using $f(x)=y$), we have
$$x=\frac{\pi }{6}+u+\frac{49 }{26 \sqrt{3}}u^2+\frac{817}{507} u^3+\frac{22975 }{26364
   \sqrt{3}}u^4+O\left(u^5\right)$$ where $u=\frac{16 y-1}{13 \sqrt{3}}$.

Make $y=0$ to get the *approximation*
$$x \sim \frac{\pi }{6}-\frac{497738471}{6776839836 \sqrt{3}}=0.481194$$