# How do we solve for $x$ in $x^5-x-1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, galois-theory, roots

What is the procedure to finding the simplest exact (or atleast a verifiable approximation to desired level of precision) correct answer to this quintic equation, and more generally to other polynomial equations of degree- 4 and higher yielding non-rational zeroes? And in this particular case, what are all the (exact or approximate) solutions? On desmos there appears to be one real x-intercept at ~1.167; I would imagine that there are up to four other non-real solutions (or fewer, should some have multiplicity greater than 1---is this possible for non-real complex roots?)

Comment: Look for [Aberth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method).

Comment: Bad news: the generic quintic is unsolvable using just radicals, and this equation in particular is the most famous example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: WolframAlpha gives five approximate solutions: the one real one, and what appear to be two conjugate pairs (non-zero b*i*).

Comment: @nicomezi:  thanks! There are apparently a lot of root-finding algorithms. Is the Alberth one the best in some way(s) (efficiency, number of steps, dare i suggest accuracy?) than other methods? And are most of them typically applied in a computer-cruncher?

Comment: According to the wikipedia page in the link "This method is used in MPSolve, which is the reference software for approximating all roots of a polynomial to an arbitrary precision.". So I am pretty confident in the fact that it has a lot of advantages. However it is not necessarily the fastest one.

Comment: Given that all the solutions (be them in the domain of interest, i.e. extraneous or not ,but supposing that the dom is C) do not conform to a non-iterative combination of algebraic operations, what would be the most accurate concise way to state the answer in terms of "x=" and "x≈" respectively? perhaps (correct notation?, where c stands for a constant):  x=c|c^5-c-1=0 ⇒ x$_{#=5}$≈[1.167, 0.182±1.084i, -0.765±0.352i].  How would you express it as membership of a set (with all approximate elements, albe some reflections about imaginary axis, non-ordered)? "x∈~{..}"? Wif sol.set contained a mix?

Comment: The Wolfram Mathworld page (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html) has everything you need about the quintic equation. If you have an irreducible quintic equation whose group is solvable, then a formula involving radicals exists. But if the group is not solvable, then you can use a Tschirnhausen transformation to transform a general quintic $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f=0$  into a Bring quintic form $x^5-x+\rho=0$, and then the roots can be found exactly using non-radical expressions

Comment: @rgvalenciaalbornoz   Wow, neat! Please consider summarizing some of that and anything else related to the question (such as what the transformation would look like for this particular fifth-degree polynomial) in an answer.

Comment: @11qq00 Next time that you post a question, please avoid math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Use Newton - Raphson .

Comment: @soupless et others: sorry! I suppose does makes it harder to search and click-into purposefully.  Thank you for adding the appropriate tag and making the title nicer.

Comment: @islamm: Fascinating! Thank you for divulging.

Comment: For something really high level, see https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1985-13-02/S0273-0979-1985-15391-1/S0273-0979-1985-15391-1.pdf

Comment: There is the complete solution for exactly this quintic equation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction#Quintic_equations. You can even see the decimal digits.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to the comment, the theory of finding roots of a polynomial equation of any degree $d$ in a **exact** way can be summarized in the following points:

- If the corresponding Galois group is solvable, then a formula using radical expressions exists. This is true for any Galois group obtained from equations of degree $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and **sometimes** for the groups of equations of higher degree. The **sometimes** can be checked depending on the nature of the specific group (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507093/why-is-there-no-solution-with-radicals-for-the-quintic-equation-x5-x1-0)).
- If the corresponding Galois group is not solvable, then the general form of the equations can be solved using non-radical expressions that involves theta functions, elliptic functions, hyperelliptic functions and more generally modular functions. In the case of the quintic equation, this can be solved using Jacobi theta functions, as proved by Hermite. In addition, one can always try to reduce the number of terms in the equation using a Tschirnhausen transformation, and indeed this approach is successful in the quintic. Thus, a general quintic can be transformed into a Bring quintic, that can be solved exactly in a complicated way, but is simpler than other approaches (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555743/how-do-you-solve-5th-degree-polynomials/1557660#1557660)).

For the example in the question, which is a Bring quintic, the associated Galois group is not solvable (in this case, it gives the symmetric group $S_{5}$, for our bad luck), so a solution involving theta functions can be found.

Of course, that means that for higher degrees the computational burden is big (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786161/solving-quintic-equations-of-the-form-x5-xa-0)), and therefore, approximate methods are suitable, like the Aberth method  mentioned in the comments.

Finally, a interesting result by [Jordan](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k290534/f20.item) said that any polynomial equation of any degree $d$ can be solved using modular functions.

A good survey of the theory can be found in the book of Bruce King "Beyond the Quartic Equation"

Comment: Thank you for the answer with links. So if I understand correctly, S_5 group corresponds to quintic polynomials, and as such no univariate degree-5 polynomials can be solved algebraically exactly?  What if some terms with non-zero real coefficients are raised to a fractional (i.e. rational power; or perhaps irrational, if not also transcendental), of non-maximum degree (e.g. <5, such as pi or sqrt10 or 23/7, possibly with magnitude less than one orand negative e.g. 1/pi or -sqrt10, in same expression with x^5), would that fall under a different group?

Comment: Are there some general patterns that can be noted, e.g. odd powers versus even?  In the case of this famous polynomial, the only non-zero even degree term is constant (considering 0 to be even, which is generally accurate although it be a special type); the other two are both odd positive real integers (incidentally also prime in any if not most sense, though I doubt that distinction matters when used as a power), separated by degree difference exceeding 1, with varying coefficient signs.

Comment: Nice questions! I will try to answer it in order 1) $S_{5}$ is the associated Galois group of the quintic in the *general* sense, this means that for *some* quintic equations the group is not $S_{5}$ and could be solvable, you have to use Galois theory to find it. The example $1024x^5-2186x^4+2186x^3-1232x^2+220x-11=0$ is solvable by radicals, because the Galois group is solvable.

Comment: 2) You can look for the associated Galois group in the same way. Because we're considering non-rationals coefficients, the algebraic independence of the coefficients over $\mathbb{Q}$ will probably play a role, but i'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: 3) This is very interesting, is it possible to find the pattern? The answer is yes, but it's not trivial. For the quintic, we have a method to know if the equation is solvable or not which is called the Cayley's resolvent (which is a polynomial). Resolvents, in some sense, condense a way to compute Galois groups. The problem is that resolvents are also complicated, so looking for a pattern translating the original coefficients in the resolvent terms and classifying which of them are solvable is difficult. Maybe a resolvent expert can help you more with this question.

Comment: 3b) For the specific form $x^{5}+ax+b$ (the example is with $a=-1$ and $b=-1$) this work was done here, showing that there are infinite solvable quintics of this form: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-26/issue-2/On-Solvable-Quintics-X5aXb-and-X5aX2b/10.1216/rmjm/1181072083.full

Comment: I would not call $S_5$ bad luck. Most quintics come out that way, and most others end up $A_5$ which also is not solvable. Missing the solvable groups is no more unlucky than missing on a Super Duper Lotto ticket.

Answer (score 3):

Similar equations can be solved by suitable power series, or by **elliptic functions**.
The equation you propose can be recast in the form:

$x^5+x+a=0$

i.e. : the Bring normal form.
Such equation defines a function $x(a)$, the so-called **Bring radical** or **Ultraradical** (not an elementary function):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

General equations of 5th degree can be solved by means of such function.

Answer (score 3):

Using Newton - Raphson

$$f(x) = x^5 - x - 1$$

$$\text{At}\quad x=   1.00,\space f(x)  =  -1.00 $$

$$\text{At}\quad x=   2.00 ,\space f(x)  =  29.00 $$

$$f′(x)=5x^4-1$$

$$x_0=2$$

$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f\left(x_0\right)}{f'\left(x_0\right)}$$

$$x_1≈1.6329$$

$$x_2≈1.3731$$

$$x_3≈1.2236$$

$$x_4≈1.1727$$

$$x_5≈1.1674$$

$$x_6≈1.167$$

Answer (score 2):

If you have a calculator that'll take fifth roots, the iteration

$$x_{n+1}=(1+x_n)^{1/5}$$

with $x_0=1$ gives

$$\begin{align}
x_1&\approx1.148698355\\
x_2&\approx1.1652928729\\
x_3&\approx1.1670872626\\
x_4&\approx1.1672806328\\
x_5&\approx1.1673014635\\
x_6&\approx1.1673037074\\
x_7&\approx1.1673039491\\
x_8&\approx1.1673039751\\
x_9&\approx1.1673039779\\
x_{10}&\approx1.1673039782\\
x_{11}&\approx1.1673039783
\end{align}$$