# I created a continuously growing polygon. However, I can't figure out how to calculate its area if I only know the perimeter.

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

I created a continuously growing polygon (instead of jumping from one value to the next when adding a side) so that I could find a polygon with an area of pi when the non-growing sides are at a length of 1. However, I can only calculate its area based on the exterior angle of the polygon measured from one of the non-growing sides. I want to be able to calculate its area when only knowing the perimeter, and I was wondering if it's possible.

All the formulas are in this Desmos link as well as a visualization of my question and a bit more info on what they do: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gtvohuh81f

Comment: You'd need to specify the angles (Yes I know you said it's in the formulas, but please break it down more), since the area depends not just on the perimeter but also on he angles. $\quad$ From there, you can triangulate the polygon and calculate it's area.

Comment: Looks like [this method of finding the area by the vertices coordinates](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html) may be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\f{\lfloor r\rfloor}$From the [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gtvohuh81f), $t$ is the “number of sides” of a continuously growing polygon with perimeter $p$ and side length $s$. Set $\frac ps=r,\frac\pi t=x$. Rewriting with a [Chebyshev U series](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/ChebyshevU/06/01/02/01/0011/), an equivalent problem is solving: $$\{r\} =\text U_{\f-1}(\cos(x)))=\sum_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{r-1}2\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma(\f-n)}{\Gamma(\f-2n)n!} (2\cos(x))^{\f-2n-1} $$ Which means inverting a $\cos(x)$ polynomial of degree $\begin{cases}\f-1&\f\text{ even}\\\frac{\f-1}2&\f\text{ odd}\end{cases}$. There are elementary inverses for the $\f=1,\dots,5,7,9$ cases, of which [$\f=7$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+ChebyshevU%287-1%2Ccos%28%CF%80+%2Ft%29%29) and [$\f=9$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+ChebyshevU%289-1%2Ccos%28%CF%80+%2Ft%29%29) do not show major simplifications in radical form, while the $\f=6,11$ cases have a single series quintic equation solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786161/solving-quintic-equations-of-the-form-x5-xa-0). The following series solution can be used for $\f=8,10,12,13,\dots$ as those cases do not simplify. Next, notice $\lfloor r\rfloor =\lfloor t\rfloor$, so the [fractional part](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) $\{r\}=r-\lfloor t\rfloor$appears: $$p = s\left( \lfloor t\rfloor +\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi \lfloor t\rfloor}{t}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}t\right)}\right)\iff \{r\} \sin\left(x\right) =\sin\left(\f x\right)$$ Now we use >[Is there any way to solve for $k$, given $\beta \sin (k-k N)-\sin (k N+k)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815107/): $$\beta\sin ((1-N)k)=\sin((1+N)k)\implies k_p=\frac{\pi p}{N+1}+\frac1{2i(N+1)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} e^\frac{2\pi i p((N-1)m+n)}{N+1}\frac{(-1)^m \beta^n}{m!(n-m)!}\left(\frac{n-2m}{N+1}+m-1\right)^{(n-1)}$$ for the $p$th real root with [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html) and substitute $(1-N)k=x,\frac{1+N}{1-N}=\f,\beta=\{r\},p=1$. Therefore: $$\boxed{r=\lfloor t\rfloor +\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi \lfloor t\rfloor}{t}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}t\right)}\implies \frac1t=\frac1\f+\frac1{2i \pi\f}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{\pi i(n (\f+1)-2m)}\f\right)\frac{(-1)^m\{r\}^n}{m!(n-m)!}\left(\frac{((\f+1)(n-2m)}{2\f}+m-1\right)^{(n-1)}}$$ shown here:

[image] [image]

One may use Wolfram Cloud etc. with the above series, or [FindRoot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), and plug it into the area function to find the area of a certain polygon given its $\frac ps$ value.

Comment: There are [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712552/p-s-left-lfloor-t-right-rfloor-frac-sin-frac-pi-left-lfloor-t-right) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717898/inverse-function-of-u-k-1-cos-frac-pix?noredirect=1&lq=1) very similar questions from the OP, one of which has an answer like the one above. Should these answers be combined or should the questions be combined? More details like when this formula should be used if there are no radical solutions will be written

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash To me it appears that your solution converts the yellow line to the blue line in your graphical representation of your answer. Is that what your solution does? If so, then that's what I've been wanting to find. In this Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gtvohuh81f there is an equation to calculate the area of the polygon using t, and since your solution seems to convert p to t, we can replace every t in the area equation with your huge equation so that we can finally calculate the area of this polygon with bizarre properties when only the perimeter is known.

Comment: Note that we can evaluate one of the sums in terms of [Fox Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) or [Fox H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function). However, the function is very general

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Do I have to use Wolfram Mathematica to compute $\frac{1}{t}=\frac{1}{\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor}+\frac{1}{2i\pi\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\exp(\frac{\pi i(n(\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor+1)-2m)}{\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor})\frac{(-1)^{m}(\frac{p}{s})^{n}}{m!(n-m)!}(\frac{(\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor+1)(n-2m)}{2\left \lfloor \frac{p}{s}\right \rfloor}+m-1)^{n-1}$ because I don't have mathematica and haven't been able to find a way to compute it. Is there a way in free Wolfram cloud?

Comment: @HarryXiro  You can use [“FindRoot” in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5BFloor%5Bt%5D+%2BSin%5Bπ+Floor%5Bt%5D+%2F+t%5D%2FSin%5Bπ%2Ft%5D-6.3%2C%7Bt%2C6%7D%5D) to solve your equation at a point or maybe modify the code for WolframAlpha. Wolfram Cloud is free to [sign up](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) for, the way I use it. For Wolfram Cloud maybe the [InverseFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) command would work as a numerical inverse or you may copy/paste the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we know P and that all sides except one are non growing sides are of unit 1 length
,
then one can find the angle of the triangle with growing side and from that find the perimeter

$(n - 1) + tan(\pi - \frac{(n-1)\theta}{2})cot(\frac{\theta}{2}) = P$

And the value of $P$ known, one can find the value of theta

The angle of the triangle with a growing side is  $2\pi - (n - 1)\theta$

And accordingly one can calculate the area of the polygon

But i still don't understand what you want to do

But if you can't understand something you can always ask

Comment: Ok so I've given what I want to work out some more thought and if I happen to only know the value of P, I want to be able to calculate t. I know the formula to calculate P knowing t but I don't know the formula to calculate t only knowing P. The formulas are in the demos graph link.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the physical significance of t

Comment: t is what you divide 2pi radians by to get theta for the exterior angle of the non-growing side. For example, a regular hexagon would have a value of 6 for t since 2pi/6 = pi/3 radians for the exterior angle of a hexagon.

Comment: the value of t would be 2pi/(angle of non growing side) and for that one can find out the value of theta if P is known