# $p = s(\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor}{t})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})})$ , make $t$ the subject?

Tags: trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've wanted to know the solution to this for years since I couldn't figure out how to get the answer, not even from wolfram alpha and this has also made me question whether if it was even possible to make t the subject of this equation. In other words, I've been trying to change it from:

$$p = s(\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor}{t})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})})$$

To:

$t =\text{equation in terms of }p\text{ and }s$

Comment: Have you drawn the graphical repesentation of your function ? Is it bijective ?

Comment: @HarryXiro You just need to invert $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$, like in [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8josy7dy8c). There could be an answer, but please include more detail like what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have made a graphical representation of the equation. I know when t is an integer that t = p, but when t is not an integer then t does not equal p. I don't know how to solve equations with the floor function in it, so I quickly got stuck trying to solve it algebraically. Here's the graph of the equation https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bpgnmuy944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eiefkmtfih):

$$p = s\left(\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi\left \lfloor t\right \rfloor}{t})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})}\right)\iff\frac ps-k=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{x}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\pi x\right)},0<x-k<1$$

Rewriting with a [Chebyshev U series](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/ChebyshevU/06/01/02/01/0011/):

$$\frac ps-k=U_{k-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}2\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma(k-n)}{n!\Gamma(k-2n)} \left(2\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)\right)^{k-2n-1} $$

Now it is just about inverting a $\cos\left(\frac\pi x\right)$ polynomial of degree $\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}2\right\rfloor$. There are elementary inverses for the $k=1,\dots 5,7,9$ cases. However, cases, like when [$k=7$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+ChebyshevU%287-1%2Ccos%28%CF%80+%2Fx%29%29) and [$k=9$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+ChebyshevU%289-1%2Ccos%28%CF%80+%2Fx%29%29) do not show major simplifications in radical form.

Comment: Yes, I would like a series solution to that since it will probably get us closer to solving the problem. Also, I tried plugging the equation in this website https://www.mathenomicon.net/mathematics-parabola/factoring/make-x-the-subject-calculator.html but it doesn't have the floor function as an option. Do you know if there are other websites that do this that have the floor function?

Comment: @HarryXiro You do not need the floor function. If you know $k<t<k+1,k\in\Bbb Z$, then  $\frac ps-k=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}t\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\pi t\right)}$. Anyways your site [does not solve](http://m.mathenomicon.net/solve-equation-inequality#results?c=solve_solvepage&v1=%255Cfrac%257B%255Csin%255Cleft%2528%255Cfrac%257B4%255Cpi%257D%257Bx%257D%255Cright%2529%257D%257B%255Csin%255Cleft%2528%255Cfrac%257B%255Cpi%257D%257Bx%257D%255Cright%2529%257D%253D3&v3=2&v6=x) the equation

Comment: When you answered the question, what does n represent? Also when you answered the question, it didn't appear to solve for t. Is that because it's not possible to solve for t?

Comment: @HarryXiro $n$ is a [sum index](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/Series_Basics.aspx). [This graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cptfhkjexe) shows the inverse for $2<x<4$. Do you understand the process of how this inverse in the graph was found?

Comment: I don't understand the process of how the inverse was found but I know now that you asked Wolfram Alpha to invert the series and get solutions for t when $2 < p < 3$ and $3 < p < 4$, thank you for that. I don't understand how to get an equation of the inverse of the Chebyshev U series that works for any value of p. Is there an equation that is the inverse of the Chebyshev U series that works for any value of p, or do you have to use Wolfram Alpha to invert the series and spit out an equation that only works when t is bound between 2 values?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "when p is bound between 2 values" instead of "when t is bound between 2 values"

Comment: This Wikipedia page looks like it shows the equation for the inverse of the Chebyshev U series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions Now it's just editing the equation so that it works for our specific case, which I don't know how to do unfortunately.

Comment: @HarryXiro That article is for the reciprocal, not inverse function, of a polynomial. It cites [this arxiv source](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403344)

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Anyways, do you know if there is an equation for the inverse function for $U_{k-1}(cos(\frac{\pi}{x}))$ or do you have to ask Wolfram Alpha to invert it for a specific value of k each time?

Comment: I think if I make a new post asking to solve for the inverse function of $U_{k-1}(cos(\frac{\pi}{x}))$, then someone else might know how to find the inverse function because solving this is a bit too advanced for me. If someone else finds a solution I couldn't have got that solution without your help, big thanks.

Comment: I found a math document that says it solved the inverse formulas of the Chebyshev polynomials of the first and second kinds: https://hal.science/hal-01705040/document 

Do you know if these formulas are actually the inverse?

Comment: @HarryXiro I saw no inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ in the article, but I did see $\sum_k a_k=U_k(x)$ and the article wrote $\sum_{k=1}^n U_k(x) c_k=n (2x)^{(2n)}$ meaning the “inverse” probably referred to  switching the $U_k(x)$ function from being outside a to being inside a sum.

Comment: Correction, the degree is $\begin{cases} k-1&k\text{ even}\\\frac{k-1}2&k\text{ odd}\end{cases}$