# Can a general quintic be solved using Inverse Beta Regularized function?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quintics

Tyma Gaidash has recently [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442541/2513) solutions to some quintics in terms of Inverse Beta Regularized function. He also [found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x/4389007#4389007) the closed form for the equation $\cos x=x$ using the same Inverse Beta Regularized function.

So, the question is: can a general quintic be solved in terms of this function?

We know that the quintics that cannot be solved by radicals cannot be solved by [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and that much more quintics can be solved in terms of Bring radicals.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: I guess the downvote was because you hadn't written your own trials and experience. Therefore I added this part to your question. (I wasn't the downvoter).

Comment: This question is also asked on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422922/can-a-general-quintic-be-solved-using-inverse-beta-regularized-function