# General formulae for Roots of 5 degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have found roots for 4 order polynomial but for 5th order Wolfram mathematicia is showing this kind of solution which is not readable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASpx7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE, take a [tour]. MSE support links, so you can post directly the link of the Wolfram Mathematica page. Moreover this post will not respect many users quality standard and can attract downvotes and be closed. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini,or%20higher%20with%20arbitrary%20coefficients.) answer your question.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439694/can-a-quintic-equation-be-solved-without-needing-a-piece-of-paper-the-size-of-a) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725226/). There are closed elliptic/hypergeometric solutions  for the quintic, but, as seen in the linked posts, the general formula would be very long due to transformations to reduce the general equation to $x^5+ax+b=0$. The similar [Thomae formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_formula) also works, but is long.

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea what Wolfram Alpha is trying to say here. There is no formula for the roots of the general fifth degree polynomial.

> Solving quintic equations in terms of radicals (nth roots) was a major
> problem in algebra from the 16th century, when cubic and quartic
> equations were solved, until the first half of the 19th century, when
> the impossibility of such a general solution was proved with the
> Abel–Ruffini theorem.

(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function )

Comment: I think Wolfram alpha is trying to say that the roots of the polynomial are the roots of the polynomials. In other words, as there is no general solution he simply say that the solution is the solution