# Reducing the general sextic to "cubic" form and other Tschirnhausen transformations of higher degrees

Tags: polynomials, radicals, transformation, algebraic-equations

**I. Methods**

Using a **quartic** Tschirnhaus transformation, one can eliminate three terms $x^{n-1}, x^{n-2}, x^{n-3}$ *without* solving a $1\times2\times3 = 6$-deg equation, a simple explanation of which is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542108/4781).

However, using a **quintic** Tschirnhaus transformation, one can eliminate three terms $x^{n-1}, x^{n-3}, x^{n-5}$ *without* solving a $1\times3\times5 = 15$-deg equation. For the case of the sextic, this reduces it to the "cubic" $z^6+Az^4+Bz^2+C = 0$.

Like the first method, the second consist of two steps.

---

**II. Step 1**

Using the general sextic,

$$x^6+a_1x^5+a_2x^4+a_3x^3+a_4x^2+a_5x+a_6=0\tag1$$

First, get rid of the $(x^5,x^3)$ terms using a quadratic Tschirnhausen transformation,

$$x^2+mx+n-y=0\tag2$$

by eliminating $x$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$ using *resultants* and collecting the new variable $y$ to get,

$$y^6+b_1y^5+b_2y^4+b_3y^3+b_4y^2+b_5y+b_6=0\tag{3a}$$

Set $b_1 = b_3=0$ and solve for $(m,n)$ which will require at most only a cubic. Thus, the partially reduced,

$$y^6+b_2y^4+b_4y^2+b_5y+b_6=0\tag{3b}$$

The next step is to get rid of $b_5$.

---

**III. Step 2**

Use a *quintic* Tschirnhausen transformation,

$$y^5+ay^4+by^3+cy^2+dy+e-z=0\tag4$$

and eliminate $y$ between $(3b)$ and $(4)$ to get,

$$z^6+c_1z^5+c_2z^4+c_3z^3+c_4z^2+c_5z+c_6=0\tag5$$

First, use the variable $e$ to set $c_1 = 0$. Second, the coefficient of $z^3$ has form,

$$c_3:=P_0d^3+P_1d^2+P_2d+P_3 = 0$$

But ***because of Step 1***, then actually $P_0=0,$ hence $c_3$ is *only a quadratic* in $d$. The three unknowns $(a,b,c)$ can then suffice to solve the three equations $P_1 = P_2 = P_3 = 0,$ making $d$ a "free" parameter. We can then use it to get rid of the $z$ term,

$$c_5:=Q_0d^5+Q_1d^4+Q_2d^3+Q_3d^2+Q_4d+Q_5 = 0$$

a quintic in $d$. Since $c_1 = c_3 = c_5 = 0,$ so the general sextic becomes a "cubic" in $z^2$,

$$z^6+c_2z^4+c_4z^2+c_6 = 0\tag6$$

This method is easily generalized to remove the three terms $x^{n-1}, x^{n-3}, x^{n-5}$ from higher equations.

---

**IV. Sextic resolvent of the sextic**

This method comes ***so*** close to [what Jerrard wanted](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Jerrard/), namely "to solve the general sextic by solving a quintic" (just like a quartic is solved by a cubic). Unfortunately $(a,b,c)$ are roots of $1\times2\times3 = \text{deg-6}$ equations, and there seems to be no way of reducing the degree. (Joubert and Valentiner also had sextic resolvents in their methods.)

---

**V. Questions about the sextic and nonic**

Of course, the next step is remove **four** terms. Hilbert, using a geometric approach involving 27 straight lines, managed to remove four terms from the nonic to reduce it to the form,

$$x^9+Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+1 = 0$$

Recall that in [Hilbert's 13th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_thirteenth_problem), he was investigating the similar,

$$x^7+Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+1 = 0$$

In [Sutherland's 2021 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09247), the impression I got (from Section 4) was that Hilbert's transformation was not in radicals and a quintic was involved. However, in [Heberle's 2021 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.08586.pdf) (p.8) it seems one can set coefficients $A_1 = A_2 = \dots = A_k = 0$ "*without solving any equation of degree higher than $k$*," so Hilbert's was just $k=4$. More details can also be found in [Wolfson's 2020 paper](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10284223). (Seems there are several papers on Tschirnhausen transformation all of a sudden, which is nice.)

So some questions are:

1. Is there really no way to reduce the degree of the sextic's $(a,b,c)$ so only quintics are involved?
2. Was Hilbert's nonic transformation and its coefficients in radicals? Or were only the coefficients in radicals? Or were neither transformation nor its coefficients in radicals?*