# Solutions to $Ax^a+Bx+C=0$ (and is it unique)

Tags: calculus, roots

I have a very naive question. Is there a closed (analytic) way to write the solution (over $\mathbb{R})$ to the equation:
$$Ax^a+Bx+C=0$$
Where $a\in \langle \frac{1}{2},1\rangle$.
and where $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}$. Or at least does anyone know any restrictions for which there exists a solution in closed form (by this I mean that can be found analytically).

Also, I've done some numerics and it also seems to me that this solution should be unique.
Can one prove that (if not what the explicit form of the solution is) that it is at least unique proved it exists and is real?

(I don't know much about this subject but it seems to me that there might be an algebraic geometry-ish kind of solution to this problem (if any).)

Comment: For $a = 5$ see [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), and for a better known more general situation, google *trinomial equation* (non-school level hits, such as [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12484/264) AND [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10100-009-0130-2) AND [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trinomial+equation%22+hypergeometric&filter=0)).

Comment: $a\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ so I don't think the case $a=5$ really helps :/ (or I don't understand how it helps at least).

Comment: Apparently I googled and commented too quickly to notice this!

Comment: If $x^a$ is the principal value of the power function, there are no negative solutions for $A \neq 0$. We can show that there cannot be more than two non-negative roots by considering the roots of the derivative of $x \mapsto A x^a + B x + C$. [A closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3426467) for the smaller root of $x^a - b x - c$ (provided a real root exists) with positive $b$ and $c$ is
$$\frac c b \hspace {1.5 px} {_1 \! \Psi_{\hspace {-1.5 px} 1}}
  {\left( b c^{1/a - 1} \middle |
  {(1, \frac 1 a) \atop (2, \frac 1 a - 1)} \right)} -
 \frac c b.$$

Comment: see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629687/how-to-find-the-zeros-of-an-equation-of-nth-degree/630480#630480

Comment: For $A=0$ or $B=0$, the solution is simple. For $C=0$, we have $x={{\rm e}^{-\ln  \left( -{\frac {A}{B}} \right)  \left( a-1 \right) ^{-1}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is rational (like $a=\frac{3}{4}$) then you can make a substitution (like $y=x^{1/4}$) and the equation becomes a polynomial equation (like $By^4+Ay^3+C=0$).

This polynomial equation will often not admit radical solutions. For example, if $a=\frac45$, you have $By^5+Ay^4+C=0$ which is famously not solvable by radicals for most $A,B,C$.

As for solutions being unique, this is not always the case. For example that last equation with $A=-1$, $B=1$ and $C=0$ is one of the rare cases with radical solutions, and there are two solutions for $y$: $y=0,1$. So two solutions for $x$: $x=0,1$.