# How does WolframAlpha solve quintic equations (5th degree polynomials)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, wolfram-alpha

There exists no general formula for quintic equations. Then how does WolframAlpha solve quintic or higher degree polynomial.

Is there a sure way to get values of roots of quintic or higher degree polynomials without brute forcing (especially non integer roots)?

Comment: Perhaps it relies on a mixture of numerical methods and trial and error?

Comment: There is a well-known method for determining which rational quintics are solvable by radicals.  Is this the sort of thing you would be interested in?

Comment: Some quintics are solvable by radicals.  You can determine whether a given quintic is one of these using Galois theory.

Comment: It *is* possible to [solve general 5th degree equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617125), but not generally with field operations and radicals only.

Comment: Wolfram alpha uses approximation to solve quintics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists no general formula for quintic polynomials from using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and $n$th roots. But numerically, we are extremely good at finding roots of polynomials very quickly.

If you have a root within a known interval (like you might get by simply evaluating it at a million points and graphing it), then naive applications of the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) will converge *extremely* quickly.

As an aside, you mention integer and non-integer roots. The rational root theorem means that it is always easy (for a computer) to find all rational roots of a polynomial. It becomes a finite guessing game. This is true brute force, but it's guaranteed to work perfectly.

WolframALpha first checks against a bank of some factorizations it has stored. Then it checks for rational roots. It is possible that it uses [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to decide if it is solvable by radicals, but I'm not completely sure. What I do know is that it very frequently resorts to raw numerical computations.

Comment: I believe it's spelled Newton-Raphson. But otherwise great answer!

Comment: Hmm, this probably means I've been mispronouncing his name for years, too. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a sure way to get values of roots of quintic or higher degree polynomials without brute forcing $($especially non integer roots$)$ ?*

Some quintics $($both reducible *and* irreducible$)$ *are* [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics).