# How to solve Nth-degree polynomial equation with terms only in N, 1 and 0?

Tags: polynomials

Namely, an equation like this:

a*x^n + b*x + c = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often called a depressed $n$th-power (i.e. cubic, quartic, &c.) equation

- $n=2$ is trivial.
- $n=3$, you can use the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), or [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) is designed for this case.
- $n=4$ also has a formula, and a corresponding [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution).
- $n=5$ can be expressed in [terms of elliptic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions) (which I only learnt yesterday, as it happens).
- $n \geq 6$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617125/solving-5th-degree-or-higher-equations).