# Understanding non-solvable algebraic numbers

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots, irrational-numbers, solvable-groups

**Background**

We know from Galois theory that the zeros of a polynomial with rational coefficients whose Galois group is solvable can be expressed in a formula that involves rational powers of the coefficients.

But we also know that for degree > $n$, there are polynomials whose Galois groups are not solvable --- let's call their roots **non-solvable**.

Yet these polynomials will still have $n$ roots (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), and if $n$ is odd, then at least one of these roots is real.

**Question**

So what are the essential differences between these **non-solvable real roots** and general transcendental numbers?

I'm like to get a better *intuitive* undersanding of the kind of numbers that are in the set of non-solvable algebraic numbers, preferably through some concrete methods for understanding their roots.

So hopefully more than just the definition that the roots of a non-solvable algebraic are *algebraic* (zeros of such polynomials) but not *transcendental* and yet also *not expressible in terms of rational powers of coefficients* (solvable by radicals).

(Thanks to DaveL. for helpful comments regarding the original question.)

---

**Edit:**
There were some really great answers.  Ideally, I would have accepted **both of these**: [answer by Balarka Sen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663428/34365) and [answer by Jack Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663437/34365).  Both give fascinating accounts, from two different points of view, as well as carry the story of higher degree polynomials beyond Galois theory into the 20th century.

As the original question was perhaps a bit vague (*What is the difference between a non-solvable algebraic number and a transcendental number?*), I've modified the title to better reflect the *question behind the question* as well as the best answers.

For related material see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540964/34365).

Comment: The subfields of the algebraic numbers I know are the rationals, [Hilbert's field](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Hilbert%27s+field%22+constructible), the ruler-and-compass constructible numbers, the conic constructible numbers, numbers expressible in terms of real radicals, the solvable algebraic numbers (numbers expressible in terms of radicals, possibly requiring the use of complex numbers in doing so). Each of these is properly contained in the next, except in the case of "conic constructible" and "expressible with real radicals", each of which contains numbers not in the other.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: So are you suggesting that all algebraic numbers are solvable (since that's the top of your nested hierarchy)?

Comment: Ooops, you're correct, it should be "solvable numbers", followed by "algebraic numbers". Or perhaps a better fix would be to replace "subfields" at the beginning with "proper subfields".

Comment: Yes, that works.  I guess my question is what can be said about the algebraic numbers that are *not* solvable, i.e. the ones sitting outside the largest proper subfield in your hierarchy?  I mean, they're either real or complex.  And assuming that they're real (which is always justified for polynomials of odd degree), what do they look like?  If we can't express them even using rational powers of the coefficients, what is the difference between them and transcendentals, i.e. the ones that are not even algebraic at all?  Surely there must be some characterisation of this difference?

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Thanks, I re-wrote it so hopefully it's more clear now?  See what you think...

Comment: I think this is a good question to ask, but might not be a good question to ask here (because I don't think there is a good answer in this format). I think you are asking "how do I become comfortable with non-solvable algebraic numbers? With solvable numbers, I believe in a simple formula, and with transcendentals (at least algebraically independent ones), I believe in an isomorphism with polynomials, but for those other numbers, what should I believe?"  If you don't know that trick with alg. ind. transcendental numbers, that would be a good thing to learn.

Comment: For what it's worth, my answer to my question is "companion matrices." They are a simple way to write down roots of non-solvable polynomials using plain old integer matrices. A more abstract version called "Kronecker's construction" was less satisfying for me, but was all I had for 5 years or so.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Great search references opening up some new vistas I didn't know about.  If you want to copy the above two comments into an answer, happy to recognise them as such.  (You hit the nail on the head in terms of what I was trying to articulate -- yes, how do I come to terms with what the top end of these hierarchies contain...  I'll have to ponder the references you've provided.  Cheers.)

Comment: @BalarkaSen: JackSchmidt's answer points to a couple of useful characterisations: companion matrices as the method for expressing the zeros of non-solvable polynomials, and algebraically independent transcendentals having an isomorphism with polynomials.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Not sure I can make it any clearer.  Jack seems to have got it.  In any event, as I'm happy with it, I'd say don't worry about it.  Thank you for being persistent though.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: That's interesting.  Why not put your thoughts into an answer instead of in the comments?  As far as what's more or less satisfactory, that's something at this point I can't weigh in on (that's why I've asked the question).

Comment: Also, there are algebraic dependencies between the different zeroes of a polynomial. In particular, things like $\sum_{r, p(r)=0}q(r)$ can be expressed in the base field for polynomial (or even most rational) functions $q$.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Your and Jack's comments above better address what I'm after.  I've invited him to add his comments as an answer.  Given its a few days, I think you can freely incorporate his and/or any others ideas into your answer.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Certainly.  There's no rush.  As you can see there doesn't seem to be a mob beating a path to this question ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How can one feel comfortable with non-solvable algebraic numbers?

The nice thing about solvable numbers is this idea that they have a formula. You can manipulate the formula as if it were actually a number using some algebra formalism that you probably have felt comfortable with for a while.  For instance $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{6}}+2$ is an algebraic number. What do you get if you add it to $7$? Well $\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{6}}+2\right)+7=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{6}}+9$ seems like a decent answer. As a side note: there actually some reasonably hard algorithmic questions along these lines, but I'll assume they don't worry you. :-)

We'd like to be able to manipulate other algebraic numbers with similar comfort. The first method I was taught is pretty reasonable:

**Kronecker's construction:** If $x$ really is an algebraic number, then it is the root of some irreducible polynomial $x^n - a_{n-1} x^{n-1} - \ldots - a_1 x - a_0$. But how do we manipulate $x$? It's almost silly: we treat it just like $x$, and add and multiply as usual, except that $x \cdot x^{n-1}$ needs to be replaced by $a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0$, and division is handled by replacing $1/x$ with $( x^{n-1} - a_{n-1} x^{n-2} - \ldots - a_2 x - a_1)/a_0$. This is very similar to "integers mod n" where you replace big numbers by their remainder mod n,. In fact this is just replacing a polynomial in $x$ with its remainder mod $x^n - a_{n-1} x^{n-1} - \ldots - a_1 x - a_0$.

I found it somewhat satisfying, but in many ways it is very mysterious. We use the same symbol for many different algebraic numbers; each time we have to keep track of the $f(x)$ floating in the background. Also it raises deep questions about how to tell two algebraic numbers apart. Luckily more or less all of these questions have clean algorithmic answers, and they are described in Cohen's textbooks *[CCANT](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Computational-Algebraic-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/3642081428/)* (A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory, Henri Cohen, 1993).

**Companion matrices:** But years later, it still bugged me. Then I studied splitting fields of group representations. The crazy thing about these fields is that they are subrings of matrix rings. So “numbers” were actually matrices. You've probably seen some tricks like this $$\mathbb{C} = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$ where we can make a bigger field out of matrices over a smaller field. It turns out that is always true: If $K \leq F$ are fields, then $F$ is a $K$-vector space, and the function $f:F \to M_n(K) : x \mapsto ( y \mapsto xy )$ is an injective homomorphism of fields, so that $f(F)$ is a field isomorphic to $F$ but whose “numbers” are just $n \times n$ matrices over $K$, where $n$ is the dimension of $F$ as a $K$-vector space (and yes $n$ could be infinite if you want, but it's not).

That might seem a little complicated, but $f$ just says "what does multiplying look like?" For instance if $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} i$ then multiplying $a+bi$ sends $1$ to $a+bi$ and $i$ to $-b+ai$. The first row is $[a,b]$ and the second row $[-b,a]$. Too easy.

Ok, fine, but that assumes you already know how to multiply, and perhaps you are not yet comfortable enough to multiply non-solvable algebraic numbers! Again we use the polynomial $x^n - a_{n-1} x^{n-1} - \ldots - a_1 x - a_0$, but this time as a matrix. We use the same rule, viewing $F=K \oplus Kx \oplus Kx^2 \oplus \ldots \oplus Kx^{n-1}$ and ask what $x$ does to each basis element: well $x^i$ is typically sent to $x^{i+1}$. It's only the last one that things get funny:

$$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
& & & & \ddots & & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 \\
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

So this fancy “number” $x$ just becomes a matrix, most of whose entries are $0$. For instance $x^2 - (-1)$ gives the matrix $i = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

This nice part here is that different algebraic numbers can actually have different matrix representations. The dark part is making sure that if you have two unrelated algebraic numbers that they actually multiply up like a field. You see $M_n(K)$ has many subfields, but is not itself a field, so you have to choose matrices that both lie within a subfield. Now for splitting fields and centralizer fields and all sorts of handy dandy fancy fields, you absolutely can make sure everything you care about comes from the field. Starting from just a bunch of polynomials though, you need to be careful and find a single polynomial that works for both. This is called the **primitive element theorem**.

This also lets you see the difference between eigenvalues in the field $K$ and eigenvalues (“numbers”) in the field $F$: the former are actually numbers, or multiples of the identity matrix, while the latter are full-fledged matrices that happen to lie in a subfield. If you ever studied the “real form” of the eigenvalue decomposition with $2\times 2$ blocks, those $2 \times 2$ blocks are exactly the $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}$ complex numbers.

Comment: (+1) Brilliant writeup!  Addresses squarely the 'psychological' aspect of working with these higher roots.  (BTW, assuming your reference was to [Henri Cohen's A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_Course_in_Computational_Algebraic_Numb.html?id=hXGr-9l1DXcC&redir_esc=y)?  Looking forward to re-reading this carefully and digesting it over some quiet time.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Yes, that is volume 1, and it focusses on $K=\mathbb{Q}$. There also the "advanced" book (vol 2, slightly diff title) which is handy if $K$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$. Quite a bit of the algorithms actually use the companion matrix idea. I actually studied ANT for a few years before realizing that the trace of a number is the trace of its matrix.

Comment: What algorithmic questions are you referencing in your second paragraph?

Comment: Equality of nested radicals has some tricky ideas, not just due to branch cuts. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660161/how-to-arrive-at-ramanujan-nested-radical-identity

Answer (score 12):

The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that every polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ (not necessarily distinct) roots in the complex numbers.

Polynomials which are not solvable by radicals have (at least one) root that cannot be written by any combination of the operations of addition, multiplication, and the taking of $n$th roots. An example is roots of $x^5-x+1$.  That doesn't mean that they don't exist, though- they're just real numbers that you can't get to using only those operations.  You can sometimes describe them with other types of operations than addition, multiplication, and $n^\text{th}$ roots, for example you can approximate them to arbitrary precision using Newton's method (much like transcendental numbers).

Transcendental numbers are different because they aren't the root of any polynomial.  $\pi$ is an example.

For algebraic numbers, we can always simplify when there is a power greater than the degree of that number.  If $$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_nx^n$$ is the smallest polynomial (with respect to degree) for which $p(\alpha)=0$, then whenever we see $\alpha^m$ for $m\geq n=\operatorname{deg}(p)$, we can rearrange the equation $$a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+\cdots +a_n\alpha^n=0$$ to solve for $\alpha^n$ in terms of $\alpha^i$ for $i\leq 1$.  So, any expression involving $\alpha$ can be rewritten using only powers of $\alpha$ between $0$ and $n-1$.

On the other hand, no matter what polynomial we evaluate at $\pi$, we can never simplify more than simply inserting $\pi$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Hi -- thanks, I followed your reasoning up to the last 4 sentences where I lost the thread (beginning "For algebraic numbers...)  Issues -- (1) what is "the degree of that number"?  Are you referring to the degree of root $\alpha$?  (2) Are you now ranging over all polynomials for which $\alpha$ is a root and choosing $p(x)$ of smallest degree for which this holds?  Are we assuming this smallest degree is $n$?  (3) "... then whenever we see $\alpha^m$ ..." -- puzzled -- where will you be looking?  Is this the $p(x)$ of smallest degree $n$, i.e. now $p(\alpha)$? ... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the degree of the root, and (trying to) appeal to the fact that $\alpha$ satisfies its own minimal polynomial.  Here's an example: $\sqrt{a}$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-a$, when $a$ is not a perfect square.  It has degree $2$, so my assertion is that whenever we write an expression containing powers of $\sqrt{a}$ it can be simplified so that the highest power of $\sqrt{a}$ is $1$.  The minimal polynomial: $\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2-a=0$ gives us $\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2=a$ a formula for $(\sqrt{a})^2$.  So, for example, $\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^3+1=a\sqrt{a}+1$.

Answer (score 4):

"this about trying to understand what kind of numbers are in the set of non-solvable algebraic numbers...."

I don't think it's easy to say much about the algebraics that can't be expressed in radicals, once you have said that they are the ones that can't be expressed in radicals.

Suppose you have some irreducible polynomial of degree at least 2, with integer coefficients. Its roots are algebraic numbers. Whether they are expressible in radicals or not is, in general, hard to tell. There is a procedure for determining the "Galois group" of the polynomial; then, there is a procedure for determining whether or not that group is a "solvable" group. If the group is solvable, then the roots of the polynomial can be expressed in radicals; if not, not.

I hope you get to study Galois Theory some day --- it is a beautiful subject.

Comment: Yes, I've studied Galois Theory (some time ago) & yes it is a beautiful subject.  However, the question I'm asking is I think beyond the scope of GT since GT provides a way to identify the separating line between polynomials whose roots can be expressed as radicals.  And, while not easy, it can help one in finding the radical expressions when they exist.  But GT does not provide any guidance for roots that "can't be expressed in radicals".  So my question boils down to: *what **other** theories / developments can say more?* Based on Jack & Balarka's comments above I'm encouraged there is more.

Comment: Then perhaps I misunderstood the question. It seems you are asking, given that an algebraic number can't be expressed in radicals, how can you handle that number? Jack says you can do it using the companion matrix, but you can do that for any algebraic number --- it's not special for the ones that can't be expressed as radicals.

Comment: Yes, on the one hand.  So granted the companion matrix representation applies to any algebraic number.  Since this includes the ones that can't be expressed as radicals gives a way of concretely accessing / expressing these.  So for me his remark was appealing because it addressed a gap -- perhaps a psychological one -- it seems to provide a tangible way to "write down" something about these roots.  On the other hand,ideally we would also be able to say more about them...  This is where my hope was that someone could tie in Elliptic functions, Bring radicals, something else?

Comment: @AKE: Asking about elliptic functions, Bring radicals, etc. would make for one or more fascinating questions.  But is this an answer to the question "So what is the difference between these non-solvable real roots and general transcendental numbers?" Maybe you could work on asking a new, more precisely focused, question.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Agreed -- more would be fascinating.  I think we've got a great collection of answers to the current question, with Jack's and Balarka's bringing in the "something more" that I was hoping for.