# find a,b,c where $\sqrt{5^{1/3}-4^{1/3}}=\frac{1}{3}(a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}-c^{1/3})$ Is it ramanujan problems?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

$$\sqrt{5^{1/3}-4^{1/3}}=\frac{1}{3}(a^{1/3}+b^{1/3}-c^{1/3})$$

find $a,b,c$

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your ideas/thoughts and what you've tried in answering this question. Why not square both sides, for example?

Answer (score 0):

By  squaring of the both sides easy to see that
$$\sqrt{\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{25}\right)$$
Since $\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{25}>0$, we need to prove that:
$$9(\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4)=\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[3]{400}+\sqrt[3]{625}+2\sqrt[3]{40}-2\sqrt[3]{50}-2\sqrt[3]{500}$$ or

$$9(\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4)=\sqrt[3]4+2\sqrt[3]{50}+5\sqrt[3]{5}+4\sqrt[3]{5}-2\sqrt[3]{50}-10\sqrt[3]{4},$$
which is obvious.

Yes, it's the Ramanujan's problem.

For example, see here: [Denesting radicals like $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} - 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871639/)

Comment: How to show? Can I have some clues?

Comment: you randomed a,b,c and squared? How to get value of a,b,c?

Comment: If I square : 
$\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4=\frac{1}{9}(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}+...)$.

Comment: I known it's ramanujan problem, but I can't solve by myself. Can you show how to solve?

Comment: @MoNtiDeaD MoonDogs Is something not clear in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \sqrt[3]{\alpha}+\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2 \beta }-\sqrt[3]{\beta^2}\right) ^2 &=& \color{blue}{\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2}}+\color{red}{\alpha\sqrt[3]{\alpha \beta^2}} +\beta\sqrt[3]{\beta}+2 \alpha\sqrt[3]{\beta} \color{red}{-2 \sqrt[3]{\alpha\beta^2}} \color{blue}{-2 \beta\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2}}  \\
&=& \color{blue}{(1-2\beta)\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2}}+\color{red}{(\alpha-2)\sqrt[3]{\alpha \beta^2}} +(2 \alpha+\beta)\sqrt[3]{\beta}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now by inspection a solution can be obtained by choosing $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=5$, giving $a=2,b=20,c=25$.

Comment: Why you noted $\sqrt[3]{\alpha}+\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2 \beta }-\sqrt[3]{\beta^2}$ and not another expression?