# Is a polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$ not solvable by any way?

Tags: galois-theory, solvable-groups

By [Galois Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) an arbitrary polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$ is **not** solvable  using [radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_algebraic_group), unlike the polynomial equation of second degree which is solvable by radicals (because of the [alternating  group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) of order 5, the symmetry group is not [soluble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group)).

Is this the only way an arbitrary polynomial equation can be (exactly) solved?

Does Galois Theory provide universal concept of general solvability?

Are there other methods except using radicals (for exact, not approximate or numerical solution)?

PS. A related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835985/is-there-any-relation-between-galois-solvability-and-integrability-of-hamiltonia)

Comment: Define "exactly solved"

Comment: @BalarkaSen Not approximate or numerical solution. Is solution by radicals an all-encompassing, universal concept of exact solvability?

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions/615899#615899) then.

Comment: @BalarkaSen, nice it seems there are other methods, however from a quick look it seems this is only for general quintics, no?

Comment: Yes. In general, higher degree polynomials are not solvable by these tricks. It is provably true for at least sextics : they are not solvable by one-variable holomorphic functions.

Comment: @BalarkaSen, some reference for this? unfortunately i do not know under what terms to search for it. thanks!

Comment: Search [Hilbert's thirteenth problem]. There are lots of references, for example, try [this](http://www.emis.de/journals/SC/1997/2/pdf/smf_sem-cong_2_1-11.pdf)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As my Group theory professor told me, giving a root of $x^2-2=0$ the name $\sqrt 2$ doesn't magically "solve" the equation. Calling a number $\sqrt 2$ is just saying "it solves $x^2-2=0$". You haven't gained any new information. Similarly, if $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial, then simply writing down $p(x)=0$ could be considered to be "solving" the equation, in the sense that, in a certain technical sense, the fact that $x$ solves that equation contains all relevant information about $x$.

Solving by radicals means that we wish to express roots of a polynomial in terms of the roots of a particular family of polynomials $x^2-a$. One reason to do this is that it means that we can numerically approximate those roots using methods to numerically approximate roots of that simpler family of polynomials. This is a common strategy in mathematics. For example, in trigonometry we try to express all quantities using $\cos$ and $\sin$. In a sense, this doesn't mean we've "calculated" those quantities, since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are just names given to particular ratios of line segments, but it does mean that we can reduce the problem of approximating various quantities to just approximating $\cos$ and $\sin$.

The [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) represents the applicaiton of this strategy to quintics. We choose a particular one-dimensional (in the vector space sense) family of polynomials and invent a special symbol to refer to a particular root of a polynomial in that family. It can be shown that in this way we can express the roots of any quintic.

Comment: +1, i really like the prologue about the symbolic meaning of "radicals" and how these can be extended to new "forms" that indeed can "solve" sth beyond. (if i could give 2 points, i would give it)

Comment: a question, how is this "theory" or "field of mathematics" called (involving "Bring radical" etc..)?

Comment: @NikosM. Which particular field do you mean? If you're interested in questions like "can we reduce solving $n$ degree polynomials to solving particular finite-dimensional familes of polynomials", then I imagine Galois theory is the place to start. (Also, it's generally not advised to accept answers too quickly, to give others a chance to answer).

Comment: So the theory involving Bring radicals is still (an extension of?) Galois Theory?

Comment: @NikosM. I've never studied Bring radicals, so I couldn't say. My suggestion would be to look for a proof that all quintics can be solved using Bring radicals, and see what kind of math is used.

Comment: Got it, thanks, from a quick look at the wikipedia link, it seems not all quintic eqs (meaning arbitrary) are solved, but it is an answer in the spirit of the question, i presume, this is *state of the art* (at least for me)

Comment: @Nikos Well, in a sense, these are all Galois theory but we usually call this field of mathematics "theory of equations". It's an official term - see wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

There are solvable quintics of course, but there is also a general solution of the quintic, using more than radicals, namely, using [hypergemetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) or [theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

See for example [Quintic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html) on MathWorld, and [Quintic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function), [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) on Wikipedia.

For the sextic, a Google search will show you several results, I'll put more references here if needed.

Answer (score 3):

With "solved by radicals" is meant that the root is expressed in closed form using coefficients, using actual numbers for coefficients you might get something like these examples:
$$x=3$$
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{13}+6i}{3i}$$
$$x= \frac{1}{6}-\frac{\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^{2/3} \left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)}{6 \sqrt[3]{-1+3 i \sqrt{3}}}-\frac{1}{12} \left(1-i
   \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)}$$

And the Galois fella tells you that there are some polynomials for which such a strange roots exist that cannot be written in form like this. It's not even about the solving (finding them), the roots themselves are such numbers that are impossible to express in this kind of expression.

Does that answer your question? If your question was if these numbers can be written in some other form - yes, why not, but it doesn't mean it will seem more precise.

For me exact form is one that defines the number and "smallest root of ..." can seem more graspable than some of the expressions above.

Answer (score 2):

There certainly are quintics that can be solved by radicals, but the point is that there are some whose zeroes *can't* be expressed in algebraic terms (sums, products, roots, fractions) of the coefficients.

Comment: great, i would prefer some elaboration on any alternative methods or formalisms for solvability of (arbitrary) polynomial equations of deegre $\ge 5$, if any?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a trinomial you can solve it analytically in terms of Lambert-Tsallis function. Look some of my previous answers.

Comment: It would be good to provide some example and references

Comment: K Z Nobrega (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1148238/k-z-nobrega), Is there an analytic solution for $x^r - x + a = 0$?, URL (version: 2023-05-05): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692907

Comment: Comments get deleted and lost, it is best to edit your answer and include all these into a more complete answer. That way people can like it and upvote it. Right now the answer is more like a footnote instead of an answer.

Comment: Hi @NikosM., I am new in the community. I still do not know how to navigate properly. I did not get your comment, because if you click in the second hyperlink you go to the answer.