# General fornula for roots of a $n-$th polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider the following polynomial equation of degree $n$

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0x^0=0$$

I know one can solve for $n=2$ using the quadratic formula. And one can solve for $n=3$ directly using Cardano's formula, or throughout facotrizing into a quadratic equation. So my question is: Do we know a formula that can solve for roots of a $n-$th polynomial equation directly? What is it?

I searched too much time for this on google but I didn't find a formula and didn't find an answer denying its existence as well, it will be very helpful if someone tell me about it, Thank you guys.

Comment: Look up Galois Theory.

Comment: There is a very complicated formula by radicals (i.e a formula using the $4$ arithmetic operations and taking roots) for equations of degree $4$. Using Galois theory it can be proved that a formula by radicals simply doesn't exist for polynomials of degree $5$ or higher.

Comment: Some (random) posts on the topic [Why can we prove mathematically that a formula to solve an (n+5) order polynomial does not exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011333), [Is a polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$ not solvable by any way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835979)