# How to determine if a quintic polynomial is solvable by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I wish to determine if $f(x)=x^5+x^4+x^3-2x^2-2x+5$ is solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$.  In other words, I want to know if its Galois group is solvable.  I haven't gotten anywhere trying to find the roots explicitly.  Also, the result for polynomials with exactly three real roots doesn't apply here.  How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem to me to be solvable by radicals

Comment: @TorsionSquid: Check out http://math.arizona.edu/~ura/053/Moore.Matthew/Final.pdf

Comment: See [solvable quintics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only general method for determining the number of real roots of a polynomial without solving the equation is the [Sturm's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem).

Its application is rather laborious, since require the calculus of a sequences of polynomials and the evaluation of table of their changes of sign in the interval in which we search the roots.

There is also a variant of the theorem ( proved by J.M.Thomas), that allows to determine the multiplicity of the roots. You can find some examples of use of this method in : B.E. Meserve, Fundamental Concepts of Algebra, pag. 160...

Answer (score 4):

According to a paper by [Dummit, "SOLVING SOLVABLE QUINTICS"](http://www.cem.uvm.edu/~ddummit/quintics/solvable.pdf), a quintic is solvable by radicals iff its Galois group is is contained in the Frobenius group $F_{20}$ of order $20$ in the symmetric group $S_5$. An algorithm and formula is provided as well.

**Abstract:**

> It is well–known that an irreducible quintic with coefficients in the
>   rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is solvable by radicals if and only if
>   its Galois group is contained in the Frobenius group $F_{20}$ of order
>   $20$, i.e. if and only if the Galois group is isomorphic to $F_{20}$,
>   to the dihedral group $D_{10}$ of order $10$, or to the cyclic group
>   $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. (More generally, for any prime $p$, it is
>   easy to see that a solvable subgroup of the symmetric group $S_p$
>   whose order is divisible by $p$ is contained in the normalizer of a
>   Sylow $p$–subgroup of $S_p$.) The purpose here is to give a criterion
>   for the solvability of such a quintic in terms of the existence of a
>   rational root of an explicit associated resolvent sextic polynomial,
>   and when this is the case, to give formulas for the roots analogous to
>   Cardano’s formulas for the general cubic and quartic polynomials and
>   to determine the precise Galois group. In particular, the roots are
>   produced in an order which is a cyclic permutation of the roots, which
>   can be useful in other computations. We work over the rationals
>   $\mathbb{Q}$, but the results are valid over any field $K$ of
>   characteristic different from $2$ and $5$.

A [related question (and answers) on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835979/is-a-polynomial-equation-of-degree-ge-5-not-solvable-by-any-way)

Answer (score 0):

This polynomial has Galois group $S_5$ (this can be shown using a theorem of Frobenius by reducing modulo primes and considering the irreducible factors), so it is not solvable by radicals.