# An unconventional algebraic function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

We all know that there are algebraic numbers that can't be expressed by radical. For example the real root of the equation $x^5-x+1=0$ (which is near $-1.16$) is algebraic but can't be expressed by radicals.

We say that a function $f(x)$ is algebraic if there exists a polynomial $p(x,y)$  with integer coefficients such that $p\left(x,f(x)\right)=0$. Obviously, polynomial functions, rational functions and irrational functions are algebraic. Is there an algebraic function (defined by a series or by an integral) that isn't polynomial, rational or irrational?

Comment: If $f$ does not need to be continuous consider $f(x) = \sqrt{1/2}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt{1/2}$ otherwise. Then $2f^2-1=0$.

Comment: @LorenoHeer $f$ doesn't doesn't need to be continuous (although it's better if it was) but $p\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: In the example i gave $p(x,y)=2y^2-1$

Comment: Let $\mathbb{E}$ be the set of polyomial, rational and irrational functions and let $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ be a partition of a subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f_1,\cdots,f_n\in\mathbb{E}$ and let $f$ be defined on $B$ by $f(x)=f_i(x)$ over $A_i$ ($i\in[1,n]\cap\mathbb{N}$). I'm not looking for functions defined this way which merely are restrictions of functions of $\mathbb{E}$ to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: We say that a function $f(x)$ is algebraic if there exists a **non-zero** polynomial $p(x,y)$  with integer coefficients such that $p\left(x,f(x)\right)=0$ **for all** $x$.

Answer (score 2):

[Rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) and root functions have a function term that is a radical expression. That are the explicit algebraic functions.
But just as there are algebraic numbers that cannot be represented by radicals, there are algebraic functions (the implicit algebraic functions) whose function term cannot be represented by a radical, see e. g. the algebraic function $f$ that is determined by the irreducible algebraic equation

$$f(x)^5-f(x)+1=0.$$

The function can be represented by series or integrals.
see e.g. [Is a polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$ not solvable by any way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835979/is-a-polynomial-equation-of-degree-ge-5-not-solvable-by-any-way/933285#933285)

Comment: Useful references: [**The Theory of Functions of Real Variables**, Vol I](https://archive.org/details/lecturesontheor04piergoog/page/122/mode/2up) by Pierpont (1905; pp. 123-137), the Speck & Hamming & Hardy ref's in [this 18 Mar 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/0zcgsZJxvSo/m/y1fxHYssFZIJ), [*Algebraic functions, calculus style*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2011.584337) by Richman (2012; [2010 preprint version](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.304.6160)), and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55016/13130).