# Exact SVD algorithm of matrix with symbolic entries

Tags: svd, symbolic-computation

I am making a library with symbolic computations which supports matrices. A matrix may have symbolic entries (eg be over the ring of polynomials of a variable $x$ ie $\mathbb{Q}[x]$).

I have implemented almost all useful linear algebra algorithms and decompositions using exact/symbolic computations (and in some cases *fraction-free algorithms*) (eg `REF`, `RREF`, `SNF`, `INVERSE`, `PSEUDO-INVERSE`, `LU`, `QR`, `RANK` factorisations/decompositions, `ROWSPACE`, `COLUMNSPACE`, `NULLSPACE` etc). The only needed algorithm which I cannot do with exact/symbolic computations is `SVD`/`EVD`. I only find numerical algorithms which solve the problem numericaly / approximately and employing "irrational" computations (eg square roots) which are not exact (*note: I dont mind if an exact/symbolic algorithm employs square roots, since I can handle these symbolicaly if needed without actually computing square roots*).

> Any exact/symbolic algorithm for `SVD`/`EVD` or any way to compute
> `SVD` using one of the decompositions I already have and which are
> exact?

*Note: the library supports arbitrary precision arithmetic (although slow).*

An online demo of the library (which is implemented in pure `JavaScript` and works in `browser` and `node.js`) is [over here](https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus/)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @kimchilover the question asks for an exact/symbolic svd algorithm, one that is not numerical and approximate, since these for example cannot be used with symbolic entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems the answer is:

**no exact/symbolic algorithm exists (or is likely to exist) for `SVD`/`EVD`**

Essentialy the problem is equivalent to the eigenvalue problem:

$$Ax = \lambda x$$

This problem is equivalent to:

$$det(A-\lambda I)=0$$

which is a polynomial equation of $n$th degree in $\lambda$ and according to [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) there is no general exact/closed form solution involving **elementary functions and operations** (which is what I need in my case, but there is no [**general closed form solution** even if more complex functions are allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835979/is-a-polynomial-equation-of-degree-ge-5-not-solvable-by-any-way)).

Since every monic polynomial can be the characteristic polynomial of a matrix, this means that there is no exact/closed form solution to the eigenvalue problem and no exact/closed form solution to the `SVD` problem (which can be rephrased as eigenvalue problem) except numerical approximations which unfortunately cannot be used with symbolic entries.