# Solution for $(4+2r) x^{(1+r)}−x−1=0$

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

I am trying to find an analytic solution for the following equation:

$$(4+2r) x^{(1+r)}−x−1=0$$

for

$$r \in \mathbb{N} $$

and

$$\frac{1}{2}<x<1, \space x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I am trying to solve for $x$. I have been unable to find a straightforward solution and I am wondering if an analytic solution exists for this equation. I understand that solving such equations can be quite complex and may not always have a simple, closed-form solution.

I found a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326984/is-there-an-analytic-solution-for-xr-x-a-0/4327024#4327024) which discusses an analytic solution for a somewhat similar equation, but I am unsure how to apply the methods discussed there to my equation.

Here's the plot of numerical solution:
[image]
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Like mentioned in the other discussion you linked, you can find analytical solutions for r = 0,1,2,3,4, or numerical approximation. Generally, such equations are difficult to solve

Comment: You accept that there isn't a simple closed form solution, and you have the numerical solution in your post, so what are you're actually asking for?

Comment: Is it hard for you to solve the equation because of the extra $(4+2r)$ factor?

Comment: yes, that's exactly my problem @ТymaGaidash

Comment: I'm sorry but there was a mistake in the equation, I fixed it (the exponent is $r+1$ and not $r$). @ТymaGaidash

Comment: Interesting problem since it is the inverse of $$r+2=\frac 1 {\log(x)}\,W_{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} x (x+1) \log (x)\right)$$

Comment: I actually found this when I was working on a problem about finding the ground state of a particular interaction matrix of a fully connected Ising Hamiltonian. Very interesting stuff. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Much improved. I think that we could also get the exact solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(4+2r)x^{1+r}-x-1=0\ \ \ \ \ \ (r\in\mathbb{N})$$

Your equation is a polynomial equation and an algebraic equation, and you can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.

For $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, you can use the solution formulas for polynomial equations and the solutions are radical expressions.

Also, the equation is a trinomial equation. See [Guldberg 1902], [Szabo 2010].

Moreover:

$$-x+(4+2r)x^{r+1}-1=0$$
$x\to -t$:
$$t+(4+2r)(-t)^{r+1}-1=0$$
$$t+(4+2r)(-1)^{r+1}t^{r+1}-1=0$$
$$t-(4+2r)(-1)^rt^{r+1}-1=0$$
$r\to\alpha-1$:
$$-(2\alpha+2)(-1)^{\alpha-1}t^\alpha+t-1=0$$
$(2\alpha+2)(-1)^{\alpha-1}\to y$:
$$t-yt^\alpha-1=0$$

Now the equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $

[Guldberg, A. S.: Sur la résolution des équations trinomes. Vidensk.-Selskab. Skrift. Math.-Naturv. 10 (1902) 1-39](https://archive.org/search?query=%22Sur+la+r%C3%A9solution+des+%C3%A9quations+trinomes%22&sin=TXT)

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

Answer (score 2):

If you look for *approximate* but accurate approximations, consider instead the function
$$f(x)=\log \left(2( r+2)\, x^{r+1}\right)-\log (x+1)$$which is much closer to linearity than the original one.

Starting at $x=1$, the first iterate of Newton method gives

$$\color{blue}{x_0=1-\frac{2 \log (r+2)}{2 r+1}}$$

What we have is $f(x_0)<0$ and $f''(x_0)<0$. So by Darboux theorem,  Newton method will converge without any overshoot to the solution.

Now, compute the **first** iterate of a Newton-like method of order $n$; the solution is **explicit**.

Here are the results for $n=2,3,4$ corresponding to "named" methods
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
r &\text{Newton} &\text{Halley} &\text{Householder} & \text{solution} \\
 10 &  0.7893256697 &  0.7897861894 &  0.7897835658 &     0.7897836101 \\
 20 &  0.8600829302 &  0.8601537395 &  0.8601535887 &     0.8601535896 \\
 30 &  0.8926124870 &  0.8926347324 &  0.8926347063 &     0.8926347078 \\
 40 &  0.9118567862 &  0.9118663299 &  0.9118663227 &     0.9118663230 \\
 50 &  0.9247493155 &  0.9247542027 &  0.9247542001 &     0.9247542002 \\
 60 &  0.9340638411 &  0.9340666479 &  0.9340666468 &     0.9340666468 \\
 70 &  0.9411457486 &  0.9411474958 &  0.9411474953 &     0.9411474953 \\
 80 &  0.9467327605 &  0.9467339152 &  0.9467339149 &     0.9467339149 \\
 90 &  0.9512656601 &  0.9512664593 &  0.9512664591 &     0.9512664591 \\
 100 &  0.9550251563 &  0.9550257301 &  0.9550257300 &     0.9550257300 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the next order, we have more than ten exact decimals.

**Edit**

It is possible to generate better and better $x_0$'s using higher order methods. For example, Halley method would give
$$x_0=1-\frac{4 (2 r+1) \log (r+2)}{2 (2 r+1)^2+(4 r+3) \log (r+2)}$$.

We still have $f(x_0^{(n)})<0$ and $f''(x_0^{(n)})<0$

Playing with the order of the method, for $r=10$, this would give

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_0^{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 & 0.7633422238 &\text{Newton} \\
 3 & 0.7889144456 &\text{Halley} \\
 4 & 0.7896940032 &\text{Householder} \\
 5 & 0.7897718056 &\text{no name}\\
 6 & 0.7897818574 &\text{no name}\\
 7 & 0.7897833306 &\text{no name}\\
 8 & 0.7897835634 &\text{no name}\\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & 0.7897836101 &\text{solution}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The problem is that the formulae become quickly messy. What can be done is to let $t=(r+2)$ and expand as a series for large values of $t$. This gives, without any loss of accuracy,
$$\color{blue}{x_0=1-\frac{T}{t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{P_n(T)}{b_n\,t^n}}\qquad \text{with}\qquad T=\log(t)$$ where the first $b_n$ are
$$\{1,2,24,48,960,2880\}$$ and the polynomials
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(T) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & T-3 \\
 2 & 4 T^2-39 T+54 \\
 3 & 2 T^3-42 T^2+189 T-162 \\
 4 & 8 T^4-295 T^3+2910 T^2-8100 T+4860 \\
 5 & 4 T^5-225 T^4+4050 T^3-24975 T^2+48600 T-21870 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$