# Find the minimum of this radical expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For $x\in[0,6]$, find the minimum of $m=x+\dfrac{96-16x}{3\sqrt{x^2+16}}$.

I used derivatives and found that the $x$ which minimizes $m$ is the positive root of
\[9x^6+432x^4-2304x^2-49152x-28672=0.\]
The approximate value is $x\approx4.71183$, $m\approx5.82339$. But I want the exact value. Since the polynomial function of degree $6$ has no formula to solve its roots, we need another method.

I can think of some alternative methods like using known inequalities or substituting to get rid of the square root, but I can't find any approaches using these methods currently.

Comment: Substitution $x=4 \tan y$ can help to get rid of the square root but it does not make it easier to find the exact minimum.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835979/is-a-polynomial-equation-of-degree-ge-5-not-solvable-by-any-way?noredirect=1 I guess anyone with Mathematica could help.

Comment: @Ajay I'm thinking that even if $x$ cannot be written as square root but the minimum can.

Comment: x can be written in terms of m though, through an [ugly quartic formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+function+x%2B%2896-16x%29%2F%283Sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2B16%5D%29). So if m has a closed form, x probably would too, through it is possible that symbolic solvers miss them

Comment: Using Sage I got the result `RuntimeError: no explicit roots found`. Not much encouraging… Numerically: $x_{\min}\approx4.7118293977$

Comment: @youthdoo here’s an idea: in your working you may have come across this equation: $$1 - \frac{(-16+96x)x}{3(x^2 +16)^{3/2}}- \frac{16}{3 \sqrt{x^2 + 16}}=0.$$ Remember that for a fraction to be zero, the numerator must be zero. So if we get everything on the LHS in a single fraction, we can obtain something less than a degree 6.

Comment: First, why you assume there is an exact solution?