# finding the roots of polynomial of degree 5

Tags: computational-mathematics, maple

I want to find the roots of $f(x)=x^5+(2-4n)x^4-10nx^3+(24n^2-16n-2)x^2+(20n^2-6n-1)x-16n^3+4n^2+4n$ with maple, but with

> solve(f=0,x);

it give me

> RootOf(_z^5+(2-4n)_z^4-10nx^3+(24n^2-16n-2)_z^2+(20n^2-6n-1)_z-16n^3+4n^2+4n)

is there any mathematical software to give me the exact roots of $f(x)$?

Comment: There is no techniques for solving polynomials with degree higher than four in general.

Comment: This is false. There is an algorithm for finding the roots of any polynomial with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general formula for the exact roots involving only radicals. In this question they explain how to do it with elliptic functions: [How to solve fifth-degree equations by elliptic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions)

I don't know of any software that does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ruffini rule? Write it on a table and try n as a parameter. The residual has to be a function in variable *n* which you have to make equal zero.

Comment: may you give me more explain? How can I find the first root?