# a conjecture of certain q-continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, conjectures, q-series

Given the squared [nome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome_(mathematics)) $q=e^{2i\pi\tau}$ with $|q|\lt1$, define,

$$\begin{aligned}F(q)=\cfrac{1-q^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-q)(1-q^5)}{1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^4)(1-q^8)}{1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^7)(1-q^{11})}{1-q^{21}+\ddots}}}}\overset{\color{red}{?}}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{12n-2})(1-q^{12n-10})}{(1-q^{12n-4})(1-q^{12n-8})}\\[1.5mm]&\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}G(q)=\cfrac{1-q^4}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-\frac{1}{q})(1-q^7)}{1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^2)(1-q^{10})}{1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^5)(1-q^{13})}{1-q^{21}+\ddots}}}}\overset{\color{red}{?}}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{12n-4})(1-q^{12n-8})}{(1-q^{12n-2})(1-q^{12n-10})}\\[1.5mm]&\end{aligned}$$

**Q:** How do we prove rigorously that the two q-[continued fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) are equal to the [q-series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Series.html)?

(if true, then the two q-[continued fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) are [reciprocals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) such that their product is [unity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(mathematics)), $F(q)\,G(q)=1$.)

Comment: Your additional info makes it much, much clearer. Don't forget those impt details. (I have also made some editing changes.)

Comment: Also, be careful with terminology. The _nome_ is just $q_1 = \exp(\pi i \tau)$, while nowadays it is more common to use its _square_, $q_2 = \exp(\color{red}2\pi i \tau)$. And note that using two dollar signs "$$" at each end centers an expression. If centering is **not** needed, then use only one dollar sign "$" at each end, ok?

Comment: More generally, you are asking, define,
$$C_{m,n}(q)=\cfrac{(1-q^n)}{1-q^m+\cfrac{q^m(1-q^{m-n})(1-q^{m+n})}{1-q^{3m}+ \cfrac {q^{2m}(1-q^{2m-n})(1-q^{2m+n})}{1-q^{5m}+\cfrac{q^{3m}(1-q^{3m-n})(1-q^{3m+n})} {1-q^{7m}+\ddots}}}}$$
If $\,2m=n_1+n_2,\,$ then,
$$C_{m,n_1}(q)\;C_{m,n_2}(q) = 1$$
Your post was just the case $m=3$, and $n_1,n_2 = 2,4$.

Answer (score 6):

(*A half-answer*.) Let $|q|<1$ and,

$$p = q^m,\quad \alpha = \pm q^{-n},\quad \beta = \pm q^n,\quad \alpha\beta = 1$$

We propose that,

$$\small C_{m,n}(q)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1-\alpha\, p^{4k})(1-\beta\, p^{4k-4})}{(1-\alpha\, p^{4k-2})(1-\beta\, p^{4k-2})} \overset{\color{red}{?}}=\cfrac{(1-\beta\,p^0)}{ 1-p+\cfrac{p(1-\alpha\, p)(1-\beta\, p)}{1-p^3+\cfrac{p^2(1-\alpha\, p^2)(1-\beta\, p^2)}{1-p^{5}+\cfrac{p^3(1-\alpha\, p^3)(1-\beta\, p^3)}{1-p^{7}+\ddots}}}}\tag1 $$

It takes only some algebraic manipulation to show that given,

$$\alpha_1 = \pm q^{\large -n_1},\quad \beta_1 = \pm q^{\large n_1},\quad \alpha\beta = 1$$

then the two products are *reciprocals*,

$$\frac{(1-\alpha_1\, p^{4k})(1-\beta_1\, p^{4k-4})}{(1-\alpha_1\, p^{4k-2})(1-\beta_1\, p^{4k-2})} \times \frac{(1-\alpha_2\, p^{4k})(1-\beta_2\, p^{4k-4})}{(1-\alpha_2\, p^{4k-2})(1-\beta_2\, p^{4k-2})}=1$$

if,

$$m =\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}\tag2$$

For example, let $m,\,n_1,\,n_2 = 3,\,2,\, 4$, and using $(1)$ and the positive case of $\pm$, we get,

$$C_{3,2}(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{12n-2})(1-q^{12n-10})}{(1-q^{12n-4})(1-q^{12n-8})} = \small\cfrac{1-q^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-q)(1-q^5)}{1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^4)(1-q^8)}{1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^7)(1-q^{11})}{1-q^{21}+\ddots}}}}$$

$$C_{3,4}(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{12n-4})(1-q^{12n-8})}{(1-q^{12n-2})(1-q^{12n-10})} = \small\cfrac{1-q^4}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^{-1})(1-q^7)}{1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^2)(1-q^{10})}{1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^5)(1-q^{13})}{1+q^{21}+\ddots}}}}$$

the same as in the post and,

$$C_{3,2}(q)\,C_{3,4}(q) = 1$$

The reciprocality is true for general $m,n_1,n_2$ that obey $(2)$. However, what remains is to show that the cfrac is indeed equal to the infinite product $(1)$.

Comment: @ Tito PiezasIII:very nice analysis,I would have given you the bounty ,had you shown that the q-cfrac is indeed equal to the infinite product.

Comment: @Nicco: Thanks. And typo has been fixed. Yes, sometimes it is understandly hard to prove a q-frac is equal to a certain q-series.

Comment: @Nicco: I've been familiar with the q-series/q-cfrac $C_{m,n}(q)$ for some time now. (See [this](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas2/).) However, I didn't realize they contain aesthetic reciprocal cfrac pairs until your posts.

Comment: @ Tito PiezasIII:if we note that $m=\frac{n_{1}+n_{2}}{2}$ is the arithmetic mean,and applying the AM-GM inequality $\frac{n_{1}+n_{2}}{2}\ge \sqrt{n_{1}\,n_{2}}$ ,then we are naturally led to the inequality $$m\ge\sqrt{n_{1}\,n_{2}}$$

Comment: The inequality implies that $m$ is bounded below

Answer (score 3):

I write $q_n = \exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}{n}$, thus $q_n^n=q$.

In [a related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457024/75794)
and [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457985/75794),
I used a formula by Ramanujan, proved by Adiga et al. (1985):
$$\small\frac{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty - (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty + (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
= \cfrac{a+b}{1-q+\cfrac{(a+bq)(aq+b)}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q\,(a+bq^2)(aq^2+b)}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^2(a+bq^3)(aq^3+b)}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}\tag{1}$$
In both cases, we had been able to simplify the result to a quotient of
Jacobi thetanulls, which implies that it is an eta quotient.
We will encounter that pattern again, so let us work it out in general.

Let me recall some two-variable Jacobi theta functions.
For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, let $w=\exp(\mathrm{i}z)$, so that expressions with
$w$ can be considered functions of $z$. Similarly, expressions with some $q_n$
can be considered functions of $\tau$.
I will need the following Theta functions:
$$\begin{align}
 \vartheta_3(z\mid\tau) = \vartheta_3(z,q_2)
 &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_2^{k^2}\,w^{2k}
\\  &= (-w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(-w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty\,(q;q)_\infty
\\ \vartheta_4(z\mid\tau) = \vartheta_4(z,q_2)
 &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^k\,q_2^{k^2}\,w^{2k}
\\  &= (w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty\,(q;q)_\infty
\\  \vartheta_2(z\mid\tau) = \vartheta_2(z,q_2)
 &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_8^{(2k+1)^2}\,w^{2k+1}
 = q_8 w \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q^{k\,(k+1)/2}\,w^{2k}
\\  &= q_8 w\,(-w^2q;q)_\infty\,(-w^{-2};q)_\infty\,(q;q)_\infty
\end{align}$$
where the $q$-Pochhammer representations are due to the
[triple product identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html).
There is another Theta function, known as $\vartheta_1$,
but we will not need it.

If you split the series for $\vartheta_3$ and $\vartheta_4$ in parts
with even resp. odd summation index $k$, you get
$$\begin{align}
 \vartheta_3(z\mid\tau)
 &= \vartheta_3(2z\mid4\tau) + \vartheta_2(2z\mid4\tau)
\\  \vartheta_4(z\mid\tau)
 &= \vartheta_3(2z\mid4\tau) - \vartheta_2(2z\mid4\tau)
\end{align}$$
and therefore
$$\frac{\vartheta_3(z\mid\tau) - \vartheta_4(z\mid\tau)}
{\vartheta_3(z\mid\tau) + \vartheta_4(z\mid\tau)}
= \frac{\vartheta_2(2z\mid4\tau)}{\vartheta_3(2z\mid4\tau)}$$
Plugging in the product representations, we get
$$\frac{(-w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(-w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty
- (w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty}
{(-w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(-w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty
+ (w^2q_2;q)_\infty\,(w^{-2}q_2;q)_\infty}
\\= w^2q_2\,\frac{(-w^4q^4;q^4)_\infty\,(-w^{-4};q^4)_\infty}
{(-w^4q^2;q^4)_\infty\,(-w^{-4}q^2;q^4)_\infty}$$
**Suppose** we are given $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ with $ab=q$.
Then we can set $w^2=a/q_2=q_2/b$ or as well $w^2=b/q_2=q_2/a$,
so the above identity takes the form
$$\begin{align}
    \frac{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty
    - (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
    {(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty
    + (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
    &= a\,\frac{(-a^2q^3;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q^{-1};q^4)_\infty}
    {(-a^2q;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q;q^4)_\infty}
\\  &= b\,\frac{(-a^2q^{-1};q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q^3;q^4)_\infty}
    {(-a^2q;q^4)_\infty\,(-b^2q;q^4)_\infty}
    \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

**Applying** the above to your question:

1. For $F(q)$: In $(1)$ and $(2)$, replace $q$ with $q^3$.
   So $(2)$ requires $ab=q^3$ now.

   Now set $a=-\mathrm{i}q_2^5$, $b=\mathrm{i}q_2$.
   Thus $ab = q^3$ and $a/b = -q^2$. This yields
   $$\begin{align}
   \mathrm{i}q_2\,F(q) &= \mathrm{i}q_2\,\cfrac{1-q^2}
   {1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-q)(1-q^5)}
   {1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^4)(1-q^8)}
   {1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^7)(1-q^{11})}{1-q^{21}+\cdots}}}}
   \\&\stackrel{(1)}{=}
   \frac{(\mathrm{i}q_2^5;q^3)_\infty\,(-\mathrm{i}q_2;q^3)_\infty
   - (-\mathrm{i}q_2^5;q^3)_\infty\,(\mathrm{i}q_2;q^3)_\infty}
   {(\mathrm{i}q_2^5;q^3)_\infty\,(-\mathrm{i}q_2;q^3)_\infty
   + (-\mathrm{i}q_2^5;q^3)_\infty\,(\mathrm{i}q_2;q^3)_\infty}
   \\&\stackrel{(2)}{=}
   \mathrm{i}q_2\,\frac{(q^{2};q^{12})_\infty\,(q^{10};q^{12})_\infty}
   {(q^8;q^{12})_\infty\,(q^4;q^{12})_\infty}
   \end{align}$$
   which confirms the claim for $F(q)$.
2. For $G(q)$: Again, use $(1)$ and $(2)$ with $q$ replaced by $q^3$.

   Now set $a=-\mathrm{i}q_2^7$, $b=\mathrm{i}q_2^{-1}$.
   Thus $ab = q^3$ and $a/b = -q^4$. This yields
   $$\begin{align}
   \mathrm{i}q_2^{-1}\,G(q) &= \mathrm{i}q_2^{-1}\,\cfrac{1-q^4}
   {1-q^3+\cfrac{q^3(1-q^{-1})(1-q^7)}
   {1-q^9+\cfrac{q^6(1-q^2)(1-q^{10})}
   {1-q^{15}+\cfrac{q^9(1-q^5)(1-q^{13})}{1-q^{21}+\cdots}}}}
   \\&\stackrel{(1)}{=}
   \frac{(\mathrm{i}q_2^7;q^3)_\infty\,(-\mathrm{i}q_2^{-1};q^3)_\infty
   - (-\mathrm{i}q_2^7;q^3)_\infty\,(\mathrm{i}q_2^{-1};q^3)_\infty}
   {(\mathrm{i}q_2^7;q^3)_\infty\,(-\mathrm{i}q_2^{-1};q^3)_\infty
   + (-\mathrm{i}q_2^7;q^3)_\infty\,(\mathrm{i}q_2^{-1};q^3)_\infty}
   \\&\stackrel{(2)}{=}
   \mathrm{i}q_2^{-1}\,\frac{(q^4;q^{12})_\infty\,(q^8;q^{12})_\infty}
   {(q^{10};q^{12})_\infty\,(q^2;q^{12})_\infty}
   \end{align}$$
   which confirms the claim for $G(q)$.

Have fun applying the above formulae to more such continued fractions.