# What can we say about roots of a quintic that is not solvable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not solvable by radicals, then what can we say about the roots of this polynomial? How might we get our hands on them? Is there anything known?

The roots are algebraic numbers (obviously) and they live in some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What properties of the roots are you interested in? We can still say they satisfy Vieta's formulas, for example. We can also talk about the Galois group of the field extension they generate.

Comment: They can be expressed as elliptic or hypergeometric functions of the coefficients, maybe?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions

Comment: @OscarLanzi really? That is the something I am looking for. Where can I read more about that fact?

Comment: @KajHansen thanks :)