# Find inverse to ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

### I got stuck and thought if you could give some guidance on how to proceed?

find inverse to

### $$y=\frac{\sqrt{x\:}+3}{\sqrt[5]{x}+4}$$

1 $$y=\frac{\sqrt{x\:}+3}{\sqrt[5]{x}+4}$$

2$$\:y\:\left(\sqrt[5]{x}+4\right)=\:\:\sqrt{x\:}+3$$

3 $$\:y\:\sqrt[5]{x}+4\:y=\:\:\sqrt{x\:}+3$$

4 $$y\:\sqrt[5]{x}\:-\:\sqrt{x\:}=\:\:+3\:-4y$$

Comment: Even Wolfram Alpha says nope http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+y+%3D+(sqrt(x)+%2B3)%2F+(x%5E(1%2F5)%2B4)

Comment: If there is a typo and the denominator is really $5 \sqrt x + 4$ then there is no real problem. Similar for $\sqrt {5x} \; + 4$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t^{10}$, with $t\ge0$. Then you have
$$
y=\frac{t^5+3}{t^2+4}
$$
that becomes
$$
t^5-yt^2+3-4y=0
$$

Then you can use [How to solve fifth-degree equations by elliptic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540964/62967), but there is no solution in “elementary functions”.

By the way, the function isn't invertible. Indeed,
$$
f(t)=\frac{t^5+3}{t^2+4}
$$
defined for $t\ge0$ has
$$
f'(t)=\frac{5t^4(t^2+4)-2t(t^5+3)}{(t^2+4)}=\frac{3t^6+20t^4-6t}{(t^2+4)}
$$
and the polynomial $3t^5+20t^3-6$ has a positive root.