# How to solve a quintic polynomial using elliptic functions with Mathematica?

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-functions, theta-functions, quintics

I followed the exact steps from [this forum post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions) to solve quintic polynomials of the form:

$x^5 - x + d$

But I got a different answer in number form from Mathematica than the original quintic polynomial root.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, where it says, $(k^2)^{1/8}$, isn't that supposed to be $k^{1/4}$?

Comment: Please show us your calculations first.

Comment: NOTE: $k^2$ has eight $8$th roots, whereas $k$ has only four $4$th roots.  Example, $k=1$.  Then $(k^2)^{1/8}$ has $8$ values,the $8$th roots of unity, whereas $k^{1/4}$ has only $4$ values, the $4$th roots of unity.

Comment: I want to solve for $x^5 - x + 1 = 0$, so we know that d = 1, here is what I put in for Mathematica: 
k = Tan[ArcSin[16/(25*Sqrt[5]*d^2)]/4]
p = I*EllipticK[1-k^2]/EllipticK[k^2]
T[J_] = (E^(2*Pi*I*J)/8)*Sqrt[2]*DedekindEta[(p+2J)/10]*(DedekindEta[4*(p+2J)/10])^2/(DedekindEta[2*(p+2J)/10])^3
T5 = Sqrt[2]*DedekindEta[5*p/2]*(DedekindEta[10*p])^2/(DedekindEta[5*p])^3
u = (1/(2*5^(3/4)))*((k^2)^(1/8)/Sqrt[k*(1-k^2)])*(T[0] + T5)*(T[1] + I*T[4])*(I*T[2]+T[3])

Answer (score 1):

```
d = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}];
Print["\nEquation: x^5 - x ", If[d < 0, " - ", " + "], Abs[d], " = 0\n"];
Print["Ordinary solution:"];
Print[x /. (x^5 - x + d // NSolve) // Sort, "\n"];
Print["Solution with Dedekind Eta:"];
k = Tan[ArcSin[16/(25 Sqrt[5] d^2)]/4];
p = I EllipticK[1 - k^2]/EllipticK[k^2];
S[J_] = Exp[2 Pi I/8]^J Sqrt[2] DedekindEta[(p + 2 J)/10] DedekindEta[4 (p + 2 J)/10]^2/DedekindEta[2 (p + 2 J)/10]^3 ;
S5 = Sqrt[2] DedekindEta[5 p/2] DedekindEta[10 p]^2/DedekindEta[5 p]^3 ;
Sign[d] (1/(2 5^(3/4))) ((k^2)^(1/8)/Sqrt[k (1 - k^2)]) (S[0] + S5) (S[1] + I S[4]) (I S[2] + S[3]) // N
```