# Apparent contradiction to Abel-Rouffini Theorem, using implicit function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, as $f(x,a)=\sum_{0\leq i\leq n} a_i x^i$.

If we assume that the polynomial that function $f$ represents has a simple zero $c_0$, i.e. $f(x,a)=p(x)=(x-c_0)q(x)$ with $q(c_0)\neq 0$, then after some calculations, we can see that the implicit function theorem allows us to find some neighbourhoods of $c_0$ and $a_0$ (where $f(c_0,a_0)=0$), and a $C^{\infty}$ function $\psi$ where $\psi(a)=c$, for all $c \in B_{c_0}$ and $a \in B_{a_0}$. Hence, $c_0=\psi(a_0)$.

In what way does this not contradict the Abel-Ruffini Theorem which states no general formula exists for pol. of degree equal or higher than 5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have expressed the zero as a smooth function of the coefficients. The theorem is about a formula involving roots. You have not proved that your smooth function can be expressed in terms of simple roots. That would be a contradiction of the theorem.

Comment: @ziggurism thanks ;)

Comment: @Winther thanks for the links ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) does not state that there do not exist *any* closed-form formula, it only says that no such formula can be expressible in [radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Solving_polynomials). That is: there is no finite formula that can be written down using only the coefficents and rational numbers under compositions of the simple algebraic functions $+,-,*,/$ and $\sqrt[n]{}$ when the degree of the polynomial is larger than $4$ (and which holds for all polynomials of given degree. One can write down formulas for special cases e.g. the roots of $x^5 - a$ is expressible in radicals. For more info see [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Solvable_groups_and_solution_by_radicals)).

General formulas can be found using special functions which typically can only be expressed using infinite series or integrals. See e.g. the related MSE questions [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291909/closed-form-expression-for-roots-of-a-polynomial).

As for your argument: the implicit function theorem only tells us that $\psi$ is a locally smooth function, it does not say anything about it being expressible in radicals so there is no contradiction.