# When does the equation $(A^2+x^2)^sx = C$ have an explicit, closed-form solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, elementary-functions, transcendental-equations

Solving a certain inverse problem reduces to solving the following elementary equation:
$$
(A^2+x^2)^sx = C
$$
Here

- $x$ is the unknown. We are interested in $x > 0$.
- $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real number.
- $A > 0$ is a fixed real number.
- $C > 0$ is a fixed number, small enough that the equation has at least one solution.

It turns out that depending on the value of $s$ the equation has one or at most two solutions. The left side is strictly increasing when $s \ge -1/2$. It is strictly increasing up to a given point, after which it is strictly decreasing, when $s < -1/2$.

**For what values of $s$ does the equation have a closed form solution?**

I know of the following cases:

- $s = -1$ second order polynomial
- $s = -1/2$ second order polynomial
- $s = 0$ trivial
- $s = 1/2$ fourth order polynomial with special form
- $s = 1$ third order polynomial, which I did not bother to solve

Are there more, and is it possible to verify that all have been found?

Note that the equation is polynomial if $s$ is rational, but not all polynomial equations have explicit solutions.

Comment: Or $x^S(A^2+x^2)=A^2x^S+x^{S+2}=C^S,S=\frac1s$. You just need the inverse of $a x^r+x$

Comment: To simplify, divide by a power of $A$: $$(1+(x/A)^2)^s(x/A)=C/A^{2s+1}$$ $$(1+u^2)^su=B$$ In other words, WLOG, $A=1$.

Comment: Use formula $(1)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636461/list-of-closed-form-special-cases-and-transformations-of-wolfram-language-s-inve)

Answer (score 3):

Because, in the general case, the equation is a polynomial equation in dependence of algebraically independent monomials ($x,(A^2+x^2)^s)$, the equation cannot be solved for $x$ by *rearranging* it by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions/operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

Other tricks, Special functions, numerical or series solutions could help.
$\ $

$$(A^2+x^2)^sx=C$$

For rational $s$, your equation is an algebraic irrational equation or an [algebraic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation) over the reals and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for such kinds of equations, e.g. for [radicals (radical expressions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) as solutions.
see e.g. [closed-form expression for roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291909/closed-form-expression-for-roots-of-a-polynomial/4247401#4247401) and related posts

for $(A,C,s,x\in\mathbb{R})\land(A,C,x>0)\land(s\neq 0)$:

$$A^2x^\frac{1}{s}+x^{\frac{1}{s}+2}=C^\frac{1}{s}$$

For rational $s\neq 0$, this equation is related to a [trinomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial) and we can use the methods for such kinds of equations.
For real $s\neq 0$, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

Answer (score 3):

In the last two years I have been working with a multi-valued function, which is a modification of Lambert function, $W_q(z)$, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046.

In the original problem, R. V. Ramos propose $W_q(z)$ as solution of the problem $$ W_q(z) \cdot \bigg( 1 + (1-q)\cdot W_q(z) \bigg)^\frac{1}{1-q} = z$$

Actually, we have been using Lambert-Tsallis function in many fields, being able to discuss closed-formula of transcendental equations, writing then in terms of $W_q$.

I have been working a bit to find your answers and make me be understood. For this reason, I decide to change usual notation. Instead of use $W_q(z)$ I will use $W_r(z)$ which is the solution of $$ W_r(z) \cdot \bigg( 1 + \frac{W_r(z)}{r} \bigg)^r = z$$
where $r=1/(q-1)$. From now on I will refer to subindex "r" always.

After a few manipulations and taking in account very relevant aspects ($A,C >0, x> 0, s \in R$), one can show that

$$ x=\sqrt{\frac{A^2}{2s} \cdot W_{2s}\bigg(2s\cdot \big(\frac{C}{A^{2s+1}}\big)^2 \bigg)   }    \  \  \  \  \  (1)$$

As previously said, $W_r(z)$ is a multivalued function. In this way, you have to test which of the solutions found will be a truly solution of your original problem.
But let's go to the considerations

$$ x>0 \implies \bigg \{ \begin{matrix} s,W_{2s} > 0  \  \  \  \  \  (2.1) \\ s,W_{2s} < 0  \  \  \  \  \  (2.2) \end{matrix} $$

**About $2.1$**

In $W_r(z)$ when $r,z >0$ at least one solution will be positive. No matter if $r>0$ is integer or not. In your case, $z>0$ when $s>0$. Following, you have some results using Eq (1). Only those in **bold** are accepted answers and they are **presented** with 5 decimal points.

\begin{matrix}
s & A & C & r & z & W & x \\
\textbf{+0.2500} & \textbf{+4.0000} & \textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{+0.0771} & \textbf{(+0.07209 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.51879 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
+0.5000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +1.0000 & +0.0386 & (-1.03717 , +0.00000i) & (+0.00000 , +4.07366i) \\ 
\textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{+4.0000} & \textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+0.0386} & \textbf{(+0.03717 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.77119 , +0.00001i)} \\   
+1.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +2.0000 & +0.0048 & (-2.00240 , +0.09803i) & (+0.09794 , +4.00360i) \\ 
+1.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +2.0000 & +0.0048 & (-2.00240 , -0.09803i) & (+0.09794 , -4.00359i) \\ 
\textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+4.0000} & \textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+2.0000} & \textbf{+0.0048} & \textbf{(+0.00480 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.19588 , -0.00002i)} \\  
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.29798 , -0.17025i) & (+0.05539 , -4.09850i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.29798 , +0.17025i) & (+0.05539 , +4.09850i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.00332 , -0.34584i) & (+0.11520 , -4.00276i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.00332 , +0.34584i) & (+0.11520 , +4.00276i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-5.69871 , +0.17602i) & (+0.06020 , +3.89874i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +4.0000 & +3.1416 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-5.69871 , -0.17602i) & (+0.06020 , -3.89874i) \\ 
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+4.0000} & \textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+6.0000} & \textbf{+0.0000} & \textbf{(+0.00000 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.00077 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.56464 , -0.31991i) & (+0.08005 , -3.28707i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.56464 , +0.31991i) & (+0.08005 , +3.28707i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.01195 , +0.65792i) & (+0.17182 , +3.14941i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-6.01195 , -0.65792i) & (+0.17182 , -3.14941i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-5.42341 , -0.34099i) & (+0.09385 , -2.98830i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +3.1416 & +4.0000 & +6.0000 & +0.0000 & (-5.42341 , +0.34099i) & (+0.09385 , +2.98830i) \\ 
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+4.0000} & \textbf{+6.0000} & \textbf{+0.0000} & \textbf{(+0.00001 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.00416 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\end{matrix}

**About $2.2$**

There is a second possibilty to exist $x>0$. If $s<0$ we have $r<0$ and if $W_r(z)<0$ it could have at least one possible solution $x>0$. The figure below illustrates behavior of Lambert-Tsallis function when $r \in Z_{-}^{*} < -1$.

[[image: Lambert-Tsallis function when <span class=]$r \in Z_{-}^{*} $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/390Lq.jpg)

**The case $\mathbf{ r < -1}$ or $\mathbf{s < -1/2}$**

If we look to such a figure, when the condition $z_b < z < 0$ is satisfied there are 2 possible $W_r(z) <0$ that could generate solutions for $x$ that can be written as

$$ z_b < \frac{r\cdot C^2}{A^{2r+2}} <0 $$
$$  \implies  C< C_{Thr}= A^{r+1}\cdot \sqrt{-\frac{1}{r+1}  \cdot (\frac{r}{r+1})^r}   $$

When $s<-1/2$, you see that there is a relationship that must be satisfied if you want to have $x>0$. Let's see somes examples.

\begin{matrix}
A & s & C_{Thr} & C/C_{Thr} & r & z & W & x\\
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1/1.99} & \textbf{+0.9787} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-1.0050} & \textbf{-0.7887} & \textbf{(-3.80307 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+6.11123 , +0.00000i)} \\
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1/1.9} & \textbf{+0.8481} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-1.0526} & \textbf{-0.6918} & \textbf{(-2.45948 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+4.80212 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-2/3} & \textbf{+0.4693} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-1.3333} & \textbf{-0.5103} & \textbf{(-1.20217 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+2.98307 , -0.00000i)} \\  
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1.0000} & \textbf{+0.1592} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{-0.4050} & \textbf{(-5.09081 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+5.01220 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1.0000} & \textbf{+0.1592} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{-0.4050} & \textbf{(-0.78573 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.96912 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1.5000} & \textbf{+0.0390} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-3.0000} & \textbf{-0.3600} & \textbf{(-3.24070 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+3.26519 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-1.5000} & \textbf{+0.0390} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-3.0000} & \textbf{-0.3600} & \textbf{(-0.64650 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.45839 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
+3.1416 & -1.5000 & +0.0390 & +0.9000 & -3.0000 & -0.3600 & (+12.88720 , +0.00000i) & (+0.00000 , -6.51131i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -1.5000 & +0.0390 & +1.1000 & -3.0000 & -0.5378 & (-1.13571 , +1.05148i) & (+2.10097 , -0.82325i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -1.5000 & +0.0390 & +1.1000 & -3.0000 & -0.5378 & (-1.13571 , -1.05148i) & (+2.10097 , +0.82325i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -1.5000 & +0.0390 & +1.1000 & -3.0000 & -0.5378 & (+11.27141 , -0.00000i) & (+0.00000 , +6.08946i) \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{+0.0105} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-4.0000} & \textbf{-0.3417} & \textbf{(-2.71659 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+2.58900 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{+0.0105} & \textbf{+0.9000} & \textbf{-4.0000} & \textbf{-0.3417} & \textbf{(-0.59515 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.21181 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +0.9000 & -4.0000 & -0.3417 & (+9.65587 , +8.06864i) & (+1.90040 , -5.23798i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +0.9000 & -4.0000 & -0.3417 & (+9.65587 , -8.06864i) & (+1.90040 , +5.23798i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +1.0100 & -4.0000 & -0.4304 & (-1.30394 , +0.30543i) & (+1.80579 , -0.20867i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +1.0100 & -4.0000 & -0.4304 & (-1.30394 , -0.30543i) & (+1.80579 , +0.20867i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +1.0100 & -4.0000 & -0.4304 & (+9.30394 , -7.49468i) & (+1.80579 , +5.12030i) \\ 
+3.1416 & -2.0000 & +0.0105 & +1.0100 & -4.0000 & -0.4304 & (+9.30394 , +7.49468i) & (+1.80579 , -5.12030i) \\ 
\end{matrix}

**The case $\mathbf{ r = -1}$ or $\mathbf{s = -1/2}$**

In the end of your question, you have mentioned that $s=-1/2$ results like an inflection point. Actually, this is an special case $W_r(z)$ function.

$$W_{-1}(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$$

There is no branch point, like Lambert Function. In this case, you can see the solution
$$ x = \frac{A \cdot C}{\sqrt{1-C^2}}$$

But there is a point that cause problem. It corresponds to $z=-1$ or $C= A^{2r+1}=1 $.

**The case $\mathbf{ -1 < r < 0}$ or $\mathbf{-1/2 < s < 0}$**

In that region, there is no branch point also. Actually if you try to apply the formula for $C_{Threshold}$ you will note that I would correspond to $C \notin R$. It says for us there is no branch point.

The solution found in this region will be positive and it will increase until the limit of $x$ corresponding to $r=1$ but for $C\neq 1$. I would have to analyse the case when $C>1$ but I believe it would generate $x<0$ which is not of your interest. Maybe, because of this you have imposed a condition of C small. Following some examples

\begin{matrix}
A & C & s & r & z & x_{analytic} & W & x_{numeric} \\
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1/5} & \textbf{-0.4000} & \textbf{-0.0253} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.02596 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.80037 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1/2.5} & \textbf{-0.8000} & \textbf{-0.1265} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.14450 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.33516 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1/2.1} & \textbf{-0.9524} & \textbf{-0.2135} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.27100 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.67584 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1/2.025} & \textbf{-0.9877} & \textbf{-0.2400} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.31567 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.77608 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1/2.00025} & \textbf{-0.9999} & \textbf{-0.2499} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.33315 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.81341 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.1416} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-0.5000} & \textbf{-1.0000} & \textbf{-0.2500} & \textbf{+1.8138} & \textbf{(-0.33333 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+1.81380 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 1):

In general we should not expect a closed-form solution when $s$ is irrational, so suppose that $s = \frac{m}{n}$ for $m \in \Bbb Z$, $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n) = 1$. Rearranging gives
$$(A^2 + x^2)^m x^n = D,$$
where $D := C^n$.

If $m \geq 0$ and $n$ is odd, then the equation is polynomial of degree $2 m + n$ in $x$, which is no more than $4$ (guaranteeing the existence of solution in radicals) if $(m, n) \in \{(0, 1), (1, 1)\}$, i.e., if $s = \frac{m}{n} \in \{0, 1\}$.

If $m \geq 0$ and $n$ is even (which means that $m$ is odd), the equation is polynomial of degree $m + \frac{n}{2}$ in $x^2$, so we can find an explicit expression for $x^2$, hence for $x$, if this degree is no more than $4$, that is, if $(m, n) \in \left\{(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2)\right\}$, i.e., if $s = \frac{m}{n} \in \left\{\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right\}$

If $m < 0$ and $n$ is odd, then multiplying both sides by $(A^2 + x^2)^{|m|}$ leaves the polynomial equation $$x^n = D (A^2 + x^2)^{|m|} ,$$ which has degree $\operatorname{max}(2|m|, n)$, which in turn is $\leq 4$ iff $|m| \in \{1, 2\}$ and $n \in \{1, 3\}$, i.e., iff $s = \frac{m}{n} \in \left\{-2, -1, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}\right\}$.

Finally, if $m < 0$ and $n$ is even (so that again $m$ is odd), then the rearranged equation is polynomial of degree $\operatorname{max}\left(|m|, \frac{n}{2}\right)$ in $x^2$, so $|m| \in \{1, 3\}$ and $n \in \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$, hence $s \in \left\{-\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{4}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3}{8}, -\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{6}, -\frac{1}{8} \right\}$.

Collating the above results, there are closed-form solutions (at least) when
$$s \in \left\{-2, -\frac{3}{2}, -1, -\frac{3}{4}, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3}{8}, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{6}, -\frac{1}{8}, 0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thats right if you are looking at the original equation. However, if the problem could be written in terms of other function, $W_r(z)$, for example, it could not be limited in this case. That is why i have put numbers. If you substitute any case, you will notice that W satisfy its polynomial equation and x can be written in terms of Wq

Comment: @KZNobrega I'd guess that most readers would consider expressions involving the function you call $W_r$ to be outside the scope of "closed form", which was a condition that o.p. imposed. Of course, different definitions of closed form can yield different answers.

Comment: In this case, We agree. Another day I saw a post of "What is a closed-form?" Maybe one should not consider my solution like closed-form. However if you assume Wq has no approximation and series inside, the final solution $x$ was written in terms of it. Maybe in this case it could be "closed form". In any case, I posted also because it gives many hints about numbers to be considered in the initial question.